# What do you do when someone calls you personally about an answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, users

It's after midnight and I'm unwinding, trying to finish off a nice concoction of [Baileys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baileys_Irish_Cream) and [Kahlúa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahl%C3%BAa) on the rocks (long day).

I get a phone call from a number I don't recognize, but what the heck, I'm buzzing and answer it anyway.

A guy asks if it's me, and I confirm. He then, without introducing himself, starts talking about an issue he's having from a [question I answered back in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185844/using-ftp-in-vba/7196612#7196612). He goes right into his problem and starts asking me about how to fix it.

I'm just dumbfounded. The whole time he's talking I'm asking myself "who the heck calls a stranger after midnight with a tech support question?"

A crazy or desperate person, right?

When he finishes his dissertation and awaits an answer, I tell him that this is the strangest call I've ever received, that I don't normally do tech support and tell him to further clarify his problem in the comments section on Stack Exchange.

He apologized for calling so late and then ask if he could e-mail me. I responded "I prefer that you didn't" and the conversation awkwardly ended.

So did I do the right thing? Point him back to Stack Exchange? :P

Maybe he will clarify a problem someone else will have in the future and prevent support calls in early morning hours?

---

### Based on the comments, here are more details for clarification:

***How did he get your number?***

My SE profile linked to my website which had my contact info; including cell phone.

I earn additional money consulting.  When I created my website, I wanted any potential client to have whatever means they prefer to contact me.  It was a conscious decision.

That being said, I changed the way I can be contacted; turns out I have a pretty low tolerance level for calls like this.

***Maybe it was a Time Zone issue***

The area code of the caller was 314; which puts him in the same timezone as me (Central).  I suppose he could have been elsewhere in the country but even if he were in Hawaii, the time would have been past business hours.

Regardless of where he was in the world, *time-zone-ignorance* is a weak argument to justify a personal phone call.

Comment: How in God's name did he get your phone number?

Comment: @Makoto My profile linked to my website which had my cell phone.  I cleared my SE profile and I'm about to update my website and remove my cell.

Comment: Ummm... could this be the same person who called you? Posted under the same question and not too long ago. http://i.stack.imgur.com/z7t2j.png

Comment: @BoltClock ROFL....YEP! That's the guy!  Guess I should not be surprised he's new to the site? Maybe add a FAQ: _Is it appropriate to personally contact a StackExchange member?_

Comment: I've had Stack Overflow users post messages to the contact form on my website about Q & A on here, but phoning you is taking it to another level of bunny boiler stalking!

Comment: *"Sorry, this phone call is off-topic."*

Comment: Thank god I'm anonymous on the web.

Comment: @usr Actually, I think that would be me. :)

Comment: You might just note that he might not be in the same timezone as you, so it's after midnight *for you* but may be a perfectly reasonable time for him.

Comment: @Puppy - and that is even more inconsiderate.  "I'll call now 'cos it's convenient for ME, stuff anyone else".

Comment: Or, more likely, simply forgetful about the possibility of different timezones.

Comment: Dude, if you posted your number on teh innernetz, people phoning after midnight is the least you should be worried about. ;)

Comment: I'd just help this guy out and point out to him the weird call time at worst. If he called it means that he was desperate to really need it. It happened to me too. I got nervous when people ignored or left my questions ;) I've learned to do everything myself and not rely on others as there are very few people willing to help another fellow human. So I understand this poor guy.

Comment: '7,508,074' questions, most of which have answers.  'very few people willing to help another fellow human', OK, if you ignore the other 7.5 million.  Sorry, but 'phone guy' is an asshole.

Comment: I've had someone from SO track me down via email, and that was weird enough.  But calling you on the phone is a whole new level of creepy.

Comment: Can I give you a call?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23: I can't imagine what it would have been like had the guy who followed me on every social site (even the ones *I don't use anymore*) and sent a "test email" to every possible address of mine that he could think of or find in mailing lists, gotten hold of my number.

Comment: Cool scenario, but I honestly don't get why this is a Meta discussion or a Stack Overflow issue.  Pretty clearly just a personal issue with a creep, which just so happens to involve a Stack Overflow Q&A.  Not the same thing.

Comment: @Jeff Gohlke: The answer might differ depending on the subject matter. A little domain-specific advice never killed anybody (well, it might starve the creepers maybe).

Comment: +1 for sparking some class replies. -1 for not paying *us*, **your consultants**, for *our* time. With a Mud Slide each, natch.

Comment: TBH this question is almost as awkward as the phone call.

Comment: And this is why they invented the voicemail, strange number? Speak the voicemail.

Comment: A phone call. Really?! Wow. Minor change required: `"who the heck calls".replace(/\bhe/, 'fu');`.

Comment: Obligatory reference: http://i.imgur.com/cTDuZJl.png

Comment: I'm going to buy a burner tonight, get slightly baked and then look for contact info on any SO users I can find. I'll be calling about unjust downvotes, clarification on null pointer exception issues, and most importantly, demanding in a loud voice "Send me teh codez!". You have been warned.

Comment: Maybe its the Facebook generation thing but I never directly leak IRL information on any site on the internet. If I were ever to freelance I'd just set up an email. If it becomes necessary to have a phone number I'd get another mobile account with another SIM card and either use one of those dual-SIM Chinese phones or get a cheapo feature-phone as a business phone and just turn off my business phone after office hours.

Comment: @slebetman It's not a matter of "the Facebook generation".  How many people post or posted with their real names on Usenet?  And with email addresses that would make it relatively easy to find a non-email contact method for them?  Oh, so and so's name is "John Doe" and they're posting with "@cs.college.edu" address?  Easy enough to snail mail or call an office phone with information like that.

Comment: "Please note that when you call me personally, this indicates you want to purchase my professional services.  My rates are XXX/hour with YYY in startup fee.  Please provide your credit card details so we may continue"...

Comment: I had a SO user email me (my phone number isn't quite so available).  I had *commented* on his question trying to get clarification.  I never did get the clarification.

Comment: Whenever you link your website, **make sure that you've anonymized the WHOIS**. Otherwise, people can get your phone number without you even posting it because they can glean it from the WHOIS record.

Comment: "I suppose he could have been anywhere in the country", like "Hawaii". Er, why not the rest of the world??

Comment: So you left your phone number on the internet and someone called you? Man. Much mystery. :P

Comment: Some of us make money consulting, @Cypher  Voice is still a very active medium for business.

Comment: @ray That wasn't really my point (which was mostly sarcastic, since I can't really take this question seriously). Tip from another professional consultant: buy a separate phone for business calls and publish that number instead. If you don't want to be bothered, you can turn it off. When it rings, then at least you know why. There are also professional answering services you can subscribe to if you need some sort of on-demand receptionist or want an automated system to forward calls during business hours and present an IVR for off-hours.

Comment: Kudos to you for your patience - after midnight, and I am relaxing with a nice drink - I'd have been tempted not to refer him back to SO, but rather to a place that is a little warmer.

Comment: The city code (area code) of a caller in the NANP (North American Numbering Plan) does not actually tell you the caller's location. The caller might have a number that has traditionally been from New York, but is working this week in Boise. Also, the US has had LNP and FMNP (Number Portability) for several years.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I suppose there's a gap here - <s>I'm not entirely sure how they got your contact information, credentials, or how they were able to successfully link it to you personally,</s> lesson learned: don't leave contact info online, but I'm of the opinion that you did the right thing.

**You are not obligated** to accept any third-party form of communication about a question you asked or answered.

If they have a question that's coherent and on-topic, then they *should* ask it here.  This way, instead of one person thinking of it, you've got a whole bunch - some of which may actually be awake/cognizant at that time of day.

I'm glad that you're removing your contact info.  Again, just note that you're not required to reply to any third party requests for clarification or a follow-up answer.  You've got a busy life, and if the person has a genuine question, this site is still up and online...

Comment: More like "You are not obligated to answer the phone when it rings."

Comment: The answer to the question seems obvious but you've succinctly spelled out the best option for individuals and the community.  Thank-you!

Comment: @BoltClock he cold have called during normal business hours (a time when I would have answered regardless) and this answer still applies as the best one.

Comment: @ray: I know, it was just a flippant remark ;)

Comment: @BoltClock sorry...Bailys + Kahlua still coursing through my veins.

Comment: So I've had this happen to me multiple times. I use my real name on the site, and I link to my company in my profile, so it's easy to figure out my office number from that. My experiences have been a lot more positive, as the people who take the effort to track me down tend to have done their research and are willing to pay for someone to help them out. Still, I can see how a lot of people might not want this kind of contact.

Comment: This answer is great except for one thing: it subtly implies that I am "obligated" to do _anything_ relating to this website. I am not!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agreed, I thought the emphasis on obligation here was weird. I don't have any obligations to any websites, ever. It kind of goes without saying. If there is a website that will attempt to impose an obligation on me, I'd like to see it; watch me do the opposite thing.

Comment: @Chris: This is definitely a tangent, but with government-specific sites, you're often obligated to enter factual information about your person under penalty of perjury.  For most sites, you're also obligated to enter your own username and password for your own account under penalty of suspension/expulsion from the site, and depending on the site or nature thereof, potential legal ramifications.  I can appreciate the sentiment, but blind defiance isn't going to accomplish much here.

Comment: I defy you, Internet! VIVA LA REVOLUTION!

Comment: "This way, instead of one person thinking of it, you've got a whole bunch..."  Not only does the asker get a better chance of receiving a helpful response, but this approach puts the response where others with similar issues can see it.  Regardless, good answer.

Comment: @Makoto: I don't think any government site can force _anything_ under penalty of perjury. They're certainly welcome to claim so, but they're lying. Until I have signed something or have established that I am under oath, I can do whatever I like, thank you very much. At this time there is no statute that can extend the power of a court to internet messaging. IANAL.

Comment: s/cognizant/cognitively active

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit +10 for the [detected implication](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261178/what-do-you-do-when-someone-calls-you-personally-about-an-answer/261230#comment46283_261179). I personally feel that's OP's doing: The question really shouldn't exist. No one should have to ask SO/SE how to handle their private life and communications. (Doing so _creates_ the implication that something needed to be checked. Answering without denouncing this _confirmed_ the implication).

Answer (score 183):

woah woah woah.... [Baileys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baileys_Irish_Cream) and [Kahlúa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahl%C3%BAa)? Trust me, slip some [vodka](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vodka) and [milk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milk) into that and you have yourself a damn fine drink.

## Mud Slide

Equal parts of the Baileys, Kahlúa and vodka mixed about two parts of milk, slip a bit of ice in if you fancy it. Fair warning, this *very* easygoing drink.

<sub>yes, this is a real answer: what you do is tell them straight, they are crazy and way out of line, then hang up</sub>

Comment: ... may be I should start slipping it into all my answers...

Comment: Or slip into the mud slide before you *compose* all your answers? It [worked out well for bobince](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#comment1619707_1732454).

Comment: Baileys, sure, but Kahlúa is way too sweet. I wish I knew of a replacement for the late great Starbucks liqueur.

Comment: @dfeuer Get the booze, mix the booze, sample the booze, not sure what happens here, wake up to find all the booze gone, your head pounding and an unrelenting desire for more. More of what? I'm never sure, until the stars align once again and the Mud doth Slide and a world of relentlessly tasty heaven joice is being drunk, just one more time. Any side effects due to blissful drinks is not my responsibility, I am not liable for your actions.

Comment: This sounds disgusting.

Comment: Well, on a hot night, outside a cocktail bar in Berlin, it kinda makes sense, (until nothing makes any sense any more:).

Comment: @MartinJames: Is that before or after you get locked in the stairwell of a hotel you're not even staying in?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to be fair, fire exits that don't fully exit, but stop you just getting back is a silly thing. Going for breakfast in another hotels restaurant, who would do that?

Comment: @thecoshman: Unpeople.

Comment: I've never stayed anyhere like that before - two hotels, (Indigo and Holiday Inn), in the same building. I could surely have got out of the stairwell, by pushing on the metal bar on ground-floor the exit door, so surely firing off an alert at reception, and possibly emptying two hotels-worth of guests onto Alexanderplatz with emergency services piling up outside.  As for breakfast, I came down in the lift, smelt bacon, and followed my nose.  How was I supposed to know that I was paying Indigo and eating in Hoilday Inn?

Comment: @MartinJames have... have you been down club again?

Comment: "Fair warning, this very easygoing drink." So true; you'll have no idea how much alcohol you're ingesting until it's too late. I wish someone told me this fact that one night in college...but maybe they did. I wouldn't know.

Comment: @Gurfuffle what do you mean? I address the question perfectly.

Answer (score 113):

I would simply reply that I normally charge $$$$/hour for tech support in office hours and $$$$$$$$$/hour for out of hours with a minimum charge of 4 hours as he doesn't have a support contract could he please supply his credit card number and a bank reference.

Bet he would have hung up rather quickly!

Comment: The OP even says they earn "additional money consulting" so this is clearly a legitimate tactic.

Answer (score 50):

We get dozens of emails each week asking if there's some way to contact a user privately, this is (basically) the reply that we give to these people:

> If users wish to be contacted off the site, they'll generally leave some method of doing so in their profile, or a link to a web site that has their contact information. If they haven't done this, then they probably don't wish to be contacted.

I used to have my Skype details in my profile, I took it out because it just became too much. That said, you *can* make yourself easily accessible to the right folks for the most part, just put an email address that you only use for buffering *in* your profile. The logic (or at least the hope) being, someone would find and use that first, not bothering to creepy crawl the rest of your details on another site.

I applaud how you kept your composure, I don't think I could have resisted the urge to play the role of a man that wasn't ... quite sane, had I been presented with the same opportunity.

*What did you say your name was? STEVE? Well, Steve, do you have any towels? Dammit man, towels! I need lots and lots of towels!*

... of course with Minecraft loaded at full volume so the chickens and sheep could be heard ...

Comment: This is starting to look too sensible, have [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A43JOxLa5MM)

Answer (score -9):

If I see a well fed, nicely groomed cat laying lazily in the foot path in front of me, I would assume it does not mind to be petted.

Same way, if you put out your number on a public website, you will have to expect that people would call - almost like if you sign your email up at various websites your email account will get spammed (Stackoverflow is surprising good with their no spamming policy).

If you do not want to take the call at certain time, switch off the phone (I assume you only put out your mobile number). If you are really peeved, separate your work and personal numbers/emails and only display your work number/email address in the public.

P.S. some VoIP services display area code different to where the caller actually is at.

P.P.S. make sure it is not a prank call, trust me prank calls can take all forms ... speaking from the point of view of a repeated victim on the receiving end.

Comment: Perfectly valid answer in my opinion. Not sure why it was down-voted.

Comment: @MartinBean maybe because OP asked what to do when contacted about SO, and not how to prevent himself from being contacted.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Oh really? So OP should answer with a recipe of mud slide or telling the caller  that he charges twice the price outside the office hours then proceed to asking the callers his credit card and reference number, is it?

Comment: This is totally silly. You might as well claim that leaving your front door unlocked makes it completely fine and okay for somebody to steal all your worldly possessions and family members. It does not. You _should_ probably keep your door locked and your phone number hidden, but not doing so does not change the fact that phoning an SO contributor at a random time of the day, not introducing yourself, badgering them for help in their own time is _obviously_ extremely anti-social.

Comment: `If I see a well fed, nicely groomed cat laying lazily in the foot path in front of me, I would assume it does not mind to be petted.` The reason so many children get mauled by dogs is because they use this logic, and find out that it's so very wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If I see a neighbour's door is open, I would assume the neighbour is at home and probably don't mind someone going over and have a chat. I would NOT assume that it's a invitation to steal everything in the house. If I see a well fed, nicely groomed cat laying lazily in the foot path in front of me, I would assume it does not mind to be petted, but I would never assume the same for a vicious looking pit bull.

Comment: @chmod711telkitty: Then you are as uneducated about animals as the children who get mauled to death by dogs. Just because they look cute doesn't mean they want you going over and invading their personal space.

Comment: Similarly, if when you put your number up on a question and answer site, people assume you don't not mind to be contacted for things related to the site, i.e. an answer you have provided. But you would not assume someone would use the number to call you up and hiss 'I know your number, I know where you live, I am coming after you'.

Comment: Even my colleagues — that is, people that I actually have a realistic expectation of hearing from — would not phone me at midnight. There is no excuse for it, and I don't know why you're trying so hard to find one. Just trolling again, most likely.

Comment: Hey! My answer is very clearly [slightly hiding the fact that that it] is an honest answer! When called, tell the person they are out of line, then server up some more delicious Mud Slide!

Comment: I had a couple of prank calls over the years ... sometimes at the midnight & it is not because I put out my number on some public sites - I had a call around 12am once,  telling me the water in the area I lived in was contaminated and I need to check it. The prankster called me 5 minutes later telling me I had to boil it then freeze it.  I went like ‘boil then freeze?’ She quickly hang up the phone. I had a guy calling me saying he was strained at the airport with no money and asked me to get him while the background noise was definitely at a party.

Comment: A couple of times around the midnight on a Saturday evening  the same stranger would call and ask me to meet him somewhere – I didn’t know the guy. He even asked me how much I would cost him a night, I was not a sex worker. More than twice someone called me in the name of job interviews & I could hear giggling on the other end. Nowadays I distrust all recruiters!

Comment: Then there was the guy calling in the early morning asking about ‘the hairy burger’ (wtf!) then there was the stranger woke me up with the call “is this Sydney” (yeah ‘accidentally’ posted my number on the web).  The list just freaking goes on …

Comment: And so, how does this answer, or anything you have said in these comments, help the OP know how to deal with people calling him over SO  in the future?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit kids get mauled by dogs due to petting cats? o_O

Comment: "I _was_ not a sex worker" interesting use of the past tense

Comment: @chmod711telkitty you're taking this way too personally. Votes express the community's opinion about the content posted. it is not a personal attack nor do we have to listen to your entire life story (though, I'd suggest switching to a new number).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: No, of course not... where did you get that idea?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit just a literal interpretation of your [comment above](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261178/what-do-you-do-when-someone-calls-you-personally-about-an-answer/261256?noredirect=1#comment46528_261256). Don't mind it. `;)`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: The logic as applied to other animals.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yep, I figured that out soon after reading. Sorry, guess [my comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261178/what-do-you-do-when-someone-calls-you-personally-about-an-answer/261256?noredirect=1#comment46586_261256) was too late to have the intended comic effect.

Comment: @thecoshman yes, we know, to an alcoholic, all problems can be solved by more alcohol (& how to mixing it) ...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit because it would be more wrong if I used the present tense.

Comment: sigh, are we wouldn't be throwing personal attacks around now, would we?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté it was over the years on a few numbers. It always amazed me how some pranksters got the number

Comment: Alright, alright. Let's just not make it into personal attacks as thecoshman mentioned, otherwise flagging & deleting will take place.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: What? Nobody's "making it into personal attacks". Chill out!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm more chill than the room temperature (<10ºC). It just seems that chmod is picking on thecosh due to his answer having a more positive score. Well, never mind, I have to go for now.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Oh that no they're just flirting

Comment: The only thing I flirt with is the bottom of the bottle

Comment: This is a good answer. If you sign your answers with 'username, phone number, email', you should expect that people would use that information, given that you've freely provided it. Since you've only linked your personal site, which indirectly pointed them to your phone number, I think it was a faux pas to have called you on it.