# Stack Overflow helped me with my problem: on which network can I share my success story?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Recently, I encountered a challenging integration issue with Spring and was unable to find help as I live in a remote Sub-Saharan African region. I turned to Stack Overflow and posted my question. To my surprise, within just a few minutes, a member of the community provided an answer that solved my problem!

I was amazed and wanted to express my gratitude to my savior. Upon checking their profile, I discovered that they work for Yahoo and live in Sunnyvale, California. It was a humbling experience, as I realized how technology can connect people from different parts of the world.

I shared my experience with the people, and they were astonished to hear that a Yahoo engineer helped me resolve my issue. In a region where people often walk for hours to access basic necessities like water, the idea of receiving help from someone on the other side of the world was incredible.

I wanted to share my story and express my appreciation to the members of Stack Overflow for their support and willingness to help others. It is inspiring to see how technology can bring people together and facilitate knowledge-sharing across the globe.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank us in upvotes, favorites, accepts, and participating in the community.

Comment: I will! just wanted to share the story

Comment: I think you just did... not sure that this is *necessarily* the best place for it, but: great to hear you had a satisfying experience

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have room here to record that. A personal story about your experience on this site is best for your own blog / website. If we allowed everyone to post about their time on Stack Overflow (or other SE sites), this place would get saturated fast (though I would not mind reading the answering adventures of Jon Skeet).

Comment: @gunr2171: Sounds like a good title for a movie.  Chuck Norris would costar.  In other news, Spring Integration sounds like a gardening problem.

Comment: We did actually have (last year maybe) a time where we could post things such as this in a special place. No one remembered in chat when I brought it up and I don't know how to find it. I'm not crazy (at least not for that reason) but it was there.

Comment: Engineers and developers from all over the world participate in Stack Overflow. There are people from [Google](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) and [Facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) who answer questions here as well.

Comment: @cupcake From where I am people walks for hours to get electric power let alone internet connection and I didn't expect people from such companies have the time to answer my question.

Comment: @Cupcake and even a few of the stackoverflow devs! :p

Comment: @tangobee, thanks for sharing! Hint: please treat your questions here as a precious resource as water on the Sahara. Read the [help] whenever in doubt and ask for guidance here on Meta whenever needed. Good luck in your endeavours!

Comment: @RobertHarvey In that movie, would Jon Skeet divide Chuck Norris by zero?

Comment: Use your "About me". It's a great place to express yourself. I see that yours is blank. Go ahead and write your experience. And yes, spread the kindness. It's not essential to help someone on SO, or even online, help anyone who needs it in any corner of the world. That's what we all are doing here in our own little way. Good luck.

Comment: This post was just so awesome, I just went on the main site and systematically upvoted all 5 of your questions. I hope the mods/system don't mind. =P

Comment: @Mehrdad: You just had to ruin it for everybody, didn't you ;)

Comment: @BoltClock: I'd been kinda dying to find an excuse to systematically cast votes on someone's posts, so this was my chance :P

Comment: @tangobee - I think you're looking for [Sotirios Delimanolis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis).  I'm sure he is happy to know that he helped you :)

Comment: +1 That's a great story, and an affirmation that SO really _is_ ushering in a new era of programming.

Comment: @John: In this post the "Thank you" makes sense. See the accepted answer, we said "you're welcome". Now your edit removed the "thank you". Rollback?

Comment: Anywhere but Fox News.

Comment: I'm glad that you got your problems sorted :-)

Comment: Great story. I am an ex-Yahoo engineer and this is so nice to hear!

Comment: Hey kids, get off my lawn! (Boy, that's the first close vote I actually feel *bad* about casting… Have a sympathy upvote.)

Comment: I saw your post again after a long time today. I am so happy to see that you are doing well and are active on Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: What's with the update? Did you ask ChatGPT to rewrite your question?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Likely. Verbosity is a signature of ChatGPT: length increased by about 30% (about 280 extra characters (incl. space))

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, I did

Answer (score 96, accepted):

It's great to hear how far you can reach someone through Stack Overflow. I'm glad the community and I could help!

I suggest you stick around. Spending time on Stack Overflow (looking back at my first questions) has made me a considerably better programmer/developer. When you improve yourself, you can then share that knowledge with the community and you end up with a nice cycle that churns out intelligent people.

Keep asking informed questions, and you'll have a great time. (I can easily say I've been addicted to Stack Overflow for the last few months (a good addiction).)

As for the question, you've shared it here, and that's a start. Though most people here have heard of Stack Overflow, so they know what good it can do. I'd consider sharing it on any social network you use and, in person, with any friend/family/colleague that would be interested.

Finally, thank you. Your words were very humbling. **Coincidentally**, my name means 'savior' in Greek, and my name day is tomorrow :) I consider this a gift.

Comment: SO is addicting for sure.

Comment: What a coincidence and I'm glad that I found SO and its awesome members. I will definitively stick around and share my experience with my community.

Comment: Happy name day! As a small gift I upvoted your post :D

Comment: What is a "name day"?

Comment: @KorayTugay It's a traditional/religious celebration. [A name is typically associated with a Saint or holy concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_days_in_Greece).

Answer (score 203):

This is the reason I log into Stack Overflow each day, so I can help people like you with your questions. I love to share my knowledge for free, just so I can help the OP or a reader in the future.

I know I'm helping to create a better central hub of information on the internet.

The best way for you to thank us is to join us. As you gain [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) (which good questions will do), you will gain [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) which will allow you more powers in the community.

Help us help you help us all.

So from all of us at Stack Overflow, you're welcome.

Comment: why is SO so positive of late... lol. Obviously voted to close this question.

Comment: *sheds a tear...*

Comment: This post and [the other one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267839/2982225) made Meta positive today, pleasant relief from rants @mehow

Comment: All your help are belong to us.

Answer (score 24):

Use the "About me" section of your profile. It's a great place to express yourself.

A lot of users write about themselves, their experiences, achievements and views on life.
I see that yours is blank. Go ahead and write your experience there.

And yes, spread the goodness by helping others. It's not essential to help someone on Stack Overflow, or even online. *Help anyone who needs it in any corner of the world.* It may be your favorite charity or just some stranger who needs your help.

> "Sometimes all it takes to brighten up someone's day is a smile or kind word, or the generous actions of a complete stranger." ~ Shaun Hick

Comment: Yes, do like I in my profile. You get badges! OMG!

Answer (score 12):

> Stack Overflow helped me with my problem, on which network can I share my success story?

To answer the title, here: On Meta Stack Overflow.

A problem on Stack Overflow is that there are new users who *just want answers* and post low quality and off-topic questions, we do our best to guide them to be high-quality members, but there are too many to help. If you succeeded, posting *how* you succeeded can help us help *others succeed*.

Stack Exchange employees are great people who aren't afraid of change, and are always happy to improve the system with the help of user feedback.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true or not -- isn't this site for questions about SO and it's workings, not for thank you notes?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Thank you notes about the sites are on-topic last I checked as long as they contain useful information. Also, meta is about ponies and unicorns too, so not strictly just workings of SO.

Comment: Well, the way I see it, I would personally rather not see meta posts "Thank you Shog9!" etc etc. Seems like way too much room to spam.

Comment: @SterlingArcher "**as long as they contain useful information**" Like specifically what is better than the rest.

Comment: But how much information can be useful in a thank you note? I thanked a mod once for a really good answer, but I did it by email

Comment: I'm not a thank-you note expert, I don't know .

Comment: I *really* doubt we'll have a frenzy of thank-you posts here...

Comment: I disagree. I don't want to see/hear "happy" stories from people who have been helped...

Comment: @mehow Then downvote. 208 people seem to have appreciated it.

Comment: @mehow Such a whiner.

Answer (score 8):

Post your story here: [10 Million Questions - Let's Share Some Stories That the Number Doesn't Convey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey), and you and the one who answered it will get a real nice Prize!

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, the best way to thank Stack Overflow is to spread the word in your local community to get people to sign up and participate.

You will increase participation from your part of the world (always welcome), plus you'll help by asking questions, answering them and participating in the community by voting on questions, answers, commenting, suggesting edits, etc.

This way, hopefully someone else from your community will be posting a similar message (which will promptly get marked as a duplicate and pointed to this one, but hey - that's part of the fun!).

Answer (score 5):

Question sounds **on which network can I share my success story?**

Take the famouse ones: FB, G+, Twitter, Tumblr, Vk.

Comment: Yip. Spreading how useful SO is is better outside of SO.

Answer (score 0):

The Stack Exchange founders have already found the way to capitalize the traffic while keeping the site free for developers. They make money on adverts, sponsored tags and headhunters.

The more good content on the site is, the more money they can make, so you've actually done a bit to pay them off - they already make a profit on the question you've asked and the answers you've become.

But you can spread the message, how good Stack Overflow is. The more people are active here, not only the more will Stack Exchange be able to earn, but also the more questions will be asked and answered! The great thing is, everyone profits!

If you are lucky enough to write a blog which is read by someone else then Google, put your profile flair there and write a few good words about SO!

Answer (score -5):

The standard I've seen on pretty much every Stack Exchange site is to thank the user via a comment on their answer. That seems to be the best place as a general rule. Though apparently a lot of people appreciate this particular question, it would get old if everyone thanked everyone here. At the very least, it should be saved for really big things, I think.

Comment: We actually highly discourage people from leaving thank you messages in comments (it even shows up when you try to type a comment, "Please don't use comments to say Thanks", or something like that). If you want to thank someone, just upvote and accept their answers. Chatty comments like "Thank you" have a tendency to get cleaned up...

Comment: @Cupcake I did not say what people in Meta want. I said what the actual practice is. I've learned recently that these often seem to be contradictory. Heck, there's something in the Guide itself that is ignored in practice here: the claim that "What does the Bible say about X" is a bad question. I even had someone flat out tell me that such questions were acceptable.

Comment: What are you talking about? What is "the Guide itself"? And in no way would "What does the Bible say about X" be an acceptable question for Stack Overflow. Even if a/the Bible had information about programming, that wouldn't be a specific enough question. You are supposed to ask about practical problems.

Answer (score -12):

Shog9 answered one of my meta questions incredibly well, and I wanted to thank him. Many people have easily accessible email addresses so I sent him a love note (by a, I mean about 491) (kidding). He responded, and that was that. I was happy, and if I know praise, I'm sure he felt good about helping.

Short answer: email is the best way in my opinion.

Comment: OMG no, don't do this. Thank people with upvotes and accepted answers. [Don't contact them externally from Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261178/456814), unless they make it explicitly clear that such contact outside of the site is actually welcome. Getting a thank you email for every question that you answer sounds like it could be a bit much.

Comment: FWIW, I didn't mind. Went into the sparsely-populated "emails from folks who aren't calling me a nazi" folder.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a mod told me since his email was there, it was ok. But Shog, <3

Comment: the only reason someone would put their email in their SO profile is if they want SO users to be able to contact them externally. if they share their email address publicly, of course you should feel free to email them. thanking someone for helping you is never inappropriate, even on the internet.

Comment: I agree with sgroves. Why would anyone publish their email on a site if they didn't want people from the site to contact them? Even the question @Cupcake indicated that the Asker made a mistake leaving his contact info out there if he didn't want to be contacted. If you put your email out there, it's assumed you want to be contacted. If there's a type of email you don't want to get, I think it's on you to indicate that. I don't get the idea that you need explicit permission to email someone who has published their email on the site in question when they didn't have to.