# Is it possible for high rep users to get rid of "Sponsored links for this tag"?

Tags: support, advertising, sponsored-tags

I understand that SO needs to have ad revenue.  I also understood way back that when you got enough rep you got rid of the (edit: prominent) ads (as you are now a valued resource generating content instead of a new user coming for answers seeing the revenue generating ads).

I have 40k on SO and now I see "Sponsored links for this tag" for Java, which I consider to be an ad.  And an annoying one too.

What do I need to do to get rid of it?

Comment: You never have *all* ads removed -- see the [privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) for the ones removed at 200 rep.

Comment: You can probably get browser extensions to get rid of them. Pretty annoying for people that mainly answer questions. I consider this enough of a burden to re-evaluate how much SO contributions I'm willing to make.

Comment: I was going to say don't be so over-sensitive, but after looking at the Java tag I agree, quite annoying. Maybe move them to the sidebar for 200+ rep users?

Comment: This is what the page currently looks like for high enough reputation users: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DCWuT.png

Comment: I already believe that SE is kind enough not showing too much ads for us with +200 rep. High rep user should be at least +10k rep. I prefer to let them showing ads for everyone and earning a lot of money, so they can invest in hiring more developers (site features) and buying more servers (site performance).

Comment: @Zanon will 40k do?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, yes, 40k is high, but the current "Reduce Ads" feature requires only +200rep. I believe that this number should be highly increased or a new privilege to be created to include "do not show sponsored links".

Comment: @Zanon to me the deal always was, active users are shown ads in the sidebar but not in the main content area. The sponsored links are breaking that deal. Showing sponsored links to a few thousand higher-rep users *who see them every day* is unlikely to generate any significant revenue - plus without the contributions of those users, there would be no site to gain revenue with in the first place

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how/why microsott is sponsoring the java tag when they effectively now (with.Net going open-source) have a competing product.  That is my biggest issue here.  If it was an Oracle add related to java and just not just "Hey look, we play nice with java" advert, it would  be a bit better.

Comment: What's wrong with just using adblock?

Comment: I'm normally not a fan of blocking ads (honestly, the site is free to join, so you might as well give a little back to help with the site's cost), but I don't like poorly-placed ads or ones that interfere with the experience of the site, which this seems to be an example of. So [here's a painfully simple userscript](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/7293-remove-sponsored-links) that gets rid of the sponsored links on tag pages (it's buggy due to the way that SE loads the ads, but it's better than nothing; I tried for an hour to get it to work every time, but nothing seems to do the trick).

Comment: @AstroCB "Give a little back" - Don't you think providing the answers and questions that attract visitors count for at least _something_?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Oh, certainly. A person of your experience on the site has made numerous contributions attracting visitors, but I meant more directly (and in general for other websites).

Comment: @AstroCB in that case you should add "Click on ads" to your answer about "How to thank this website?" - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269683/53897

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Don't worry; I agree with you, so there's no need to argue. I just meant that in general for other sites.

Answer (score 51):

Yes please.

As it stands, the Sponsored Links box wastes valuable vertical space on a page that is an important tool for power users. (It could also use a looking-at by the design team.)

Please do one of the following for power users (200+ rep or more, maybe 1000+?):

- move it  to the right hand sidebar
- contract it vertically and make it expandable
- turn the tag excerpt into a set of tabs and make the Sponsored Links a tab
- remove it altogether

To me, the implicit deal has always been that power users are shown ads only in the sidebar to the right. That always felt right; the Sponsored Links box on its current position doesn't.

Comment: I've never seen these sponsored links before on a tag that didn't have full sponsorship (i,e, [tag:android]).  Is this somewhat common and I've just never noticed?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I asked myself the same question!

Comment: I'd say give it as a privilege at 1,000 reputation.

Comment: I think it should be higher, perhaps 2,000. I guess though it is up to SE to work out how the conversions track, whether many people above XYZ rep even click those links.

Answer (score 29):

First, please note [this is not the first time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24033/bring-back-the-200-rep-level-to-not-see-sponsored-header-ads) this issue has been raised.

To address a few of the points made:

Since we started offering them, nothing has changed regarding how tag sponsorships are displayed. Up to five text links, 80 character max, 100x100 logo, 18x16 tag icon for trademark holders. They've always been a way for advertisers to reach both users like you, @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, those sub-200 rep, and all in between. While you may prefer them not to be able to do so, that is how sponsorships function at the moment. More on that in a bit.

Also note that the [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) to limit ads to high-rep users (defined as those accumulating more than 200 rep) pertains to leaderboard-sized ads on question pages.

Sponsoring tags of content that is not copyrighted is not new. Mozilla sponsors [html5-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5-apps), New Relic sponsored [apm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apm) (though that just expired at the end of 2014), Acquia at one time sponsored [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal).

**All that said: we have a team meeting early next week and will have a serious discussion about tag sponsorships, taking your concerns specifically into account.** Relevant updates will appear here.

---

**1/6/2015:** Quick update: while the sponsorship in question is no longer active, we're still taking everyone's issues with it into account. More updates to follow.

---

**1/8/2015:** There is an update being worked on right now that will, we hope, make how you view tag sponsorships better. When we're closer to rolling out the change I'll be able to provide more information, but I'll say for now that I believe it addresses your concerns and allows your normal use of the tag pages to persist. I intend to have it live and in the wild by next week.

Comment: A usable compromise would be to move them to the sidebar as suggested by @Pekka 웃.  I would really like you to tell us what is most important to SO these days - sponsorships or the high-rep users?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, *most* important to us is probably getting them to reboot Firefly, ideally on Netflix, so we can binge-watch it.  But after that, it's you guys. Stevve's description of "why MS would want to advertise here", is a different thing than "how can we improve this experience for our best users," which is always the top question.  No one - MS included - will have much use for us without the efforts of users like you, and we never lose sight of that.

Comment: @Jaydles if you get Firefly rebooted I'll live with the sidebar (and then watch Firefly instead of linger out on SO).

Comment: A pragmatic approach may be to have them disabled for for users off of 100k rep or more. That removes like a dozen eyeballs and makes it technically removable while providing an out so people can;t complain without really impacting your ad rates.

Comment: @ArtB "Power users" are very likely "prescriber" too. So one power user eyeball might have much more value than hundreds of <100 rep users.

Answer (score 19):

My current (more than perfect) solution is [AdBlock](https://getadblock.com).

[image]

Comment: Blacklist, please, unless you noscript generally.

Comment: if you're on chrome, adblock is better. (they're not affiliated btw)

Comment: If you're on Firefox, Adblock Edge is better, and is also not affiliated with advertisers.

Comment: Disconnect.me works fine to, or AdBlock Plus

Answer (score 12):

I don't have my monitor set at a particularly high resolution, so the current advertisement on the list of Java questions takes up enough of my screen to make the site quite unpleasant to use.  Having said that, I don't mind seeing such advertisements a few times.

But once I have decided that I am not interested in developing my Java code in Visual Studio, and I have no need for its "unlimited free private repos" or its "professional tools that complement" my Java code; then there is  no further value to Microsoft or to Stack Exchange in continuing to show me this advertisement.

What such advertisements really need is a "dismiss permanently" link, or "never show me this again".

Also, about half of the wasted vertical space in the Visual Studio advertisement is whitespace.  Why?

Comment: Stack Exchange still benefits from just [serving the ads](http://help.adzerk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203252155-How-Adzerk-Reports-Impressions-and-Clicks), even if the users aren't likely to click them. However, it _would_ be more to their interest to serve relevant ads that the user would be interested in, and not repeat those that have already been viewed.

Comment: It is in Microsoft's PR interest to remind you that they are making efforts to appeal to the open-source and non-MS-tech community like this, even if you're not going to use their services directly. Advertising isn't always about sales.

Comment: It is not in Microsoft's, or SE's PR interest to annoy me several times a day by reminding me that they set zero value on my convenience. If it were about sales, we would have some power, because we could start a concerted boycott that would make that form of ad negatively correlated with sales.

Comment: This is an *excellent* point. Relevance can be an asset to advertisers. As I mentioned in my answer, we're taking these suggestions into account.

Comment: Unfortunately, no matter how many times a day Microsoft choose to annoy me, it is not possible for me to buy less Visual Studio than I already do.

Comment: @DavidWallace I also cannot possibly buy less Visual Studio, but I can use Linux on more of my computers.

Comment: Unfortunately, where I live, it's basically impossible to buy a new computer without some version of Windows pre-installed.

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I would like to keep ads even if I do have a higher rep. The amount of ads on an SO page are really not that many. Instead I'd rather they presented me with better ads :).

Answer (score 7):

My current (less than perfect) solution is to keep the questions page partially scrolled down, so that I get as many new questions as possible on my screen, and don't see the ad. The down side is not seeing the reputation changes and other useful links at the top of the page.

[image]

BTW, if you must have this ad in the Java tag, you can at least eliminate the empty space that takes half the space of this ad.

Another manual solution for Firefox :

When you see this annoying Ad, hit CTRL + SHIFT + C.

You'll see this :

[image]

Find the ad div (adzerk...), right click and choose Delete Node.

Gets rid of the Ad until you reload the page, but since I mostly refresh the page by hitting the "x questions with new activity" button, I rarely reload the page.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the top-bar isn't pinned so it's always visible.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils If you want a (partially) frozen top bar, take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101385/should-the-top-navigation-be-frozen-optional