# "Sponsored links for this tag" box is taller than its content

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, sponsored-tags

Today I firstly recognized the "Sponsored links for this tag" box for the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag. It has a lot of empty space at it's bottom, which could be used for more useful things.

[image]

Since there is some discussion about the usefulness of that box, it would at least be most appropriate to not make it larger than it needs to be.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281521/is-it-possible-for-high-rep-users-to-get-rid-of-sponsored-links-for-this-tag

Comment: (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281521/1798593) is related, but not a duplicate. That question proposes completely sparing high rep uses from the box. This one proposes sparing all users from the excessive white space in the box. One would require a policy change. This one recommends fixing what is really a bug, the failure to size the box to its contents.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan It's highly related though; while this may not be an exact duplicate, the aims of both are the same as they center around the design of the box itself as the problem.

Comment: It's not remotely a duplicate. The only similarity is that they both concern the same UI element. Nothing else about them is the same, and everyone who bandwagon-voted to close this question should feel bad.

Answer (score 13):

The sponsored tags give clients up to 5 text links, but they don't always use them. The way tag sponsorships currently exist, the box is always the same size, which can lead to the white space you see. This will be addressed at the same time we address tag sponsorships in general.

Comment: shouldn't you have a tag to indicate you are a staff member?  I had to look at your profile to find out.  Just a comment.

Comment: @Chrismas007 I find most SE staff don't have tags of any kind on SO, the only indication is in their profile.

Comment: Regarding the answer, I believe that this is a bug that should be fixed (with low priority). If the sponsor does not use the full space, it would be simple to reduce the box size to remove the empty space.

Comment: I'm working on getting a diamond added. As I typically don't "moderate", nor am I a developer, I've never needed the diamond before as the text in my profile usually suffices. The logo size is 100x100, which limits the ability to shrink the box. We'll provide updates once we have a viable solution.

Comment: Maybe staff members should have a different character @DannyMiller... But I guess that would be a different meta topic...

Comment: @DannyMiller Perhaps there's a small potential for a new symbol to be introduced in the future in order to mark out staff members?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246678/should-se-staff-have-a-special-character-in-their-user-name @cybermonkey

Comment: "I'm working on getting a diamond added" - ???

Comment: @nicael http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators

Comment: @Aje Ha, of course I know who are mods. But I don't get how can employee work to get the diamond. What work is it supposed to be?

Comment: @nicael Message the guy down the hall and tell him to give you mod powers?