# Ads are using Flash once again

Tags: support, advertising

In relation to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286172/why-does-stack-overflow-use-flash) which was isolated to a single campaign, I'm noticing that a few ads are using Flash once again on the site.

The main reason I noticed:  until Adobe can sort out [their zero-day exploits](http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/07/adobe-flash-exploit-that-was-leaked-by-hacking-team-goes-wild-patch-now/), Flash on my machine is click-to-play.

I'm noticing that this particular Flash call is coming from adsafeprotected.com.  It happens on select pages with adverts, but not all of them; I notice it on questions with the "Windows Azure" advert running.  If more information is required, I'd be happy to provide it.

EDIT:  It seems that they're back at it again.  It's yet another Windows Azure advert and they're indeed running Flash.

Comment: Flash?  Really?  Flash is so 2010.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, It's not that I like Flash, but in 1999 it was widely said that Flash is deprecated and would soon be replaced by Dynamic HTML (and unless you are too young to remember DHTML, which is by now quite possible, you will remember how that turned out). If there is ever an atomic war the two things that will survive are the cockroaches and Flash, and I'm not sure about the cockroaches.

Comment: Flash can take a drought much, much better than roaches. Roaches are doomed, but we will still have flash animations of them to play.

Comment: To the sidebar about flash: I think we're damn close with HTML5, especially canvas, CSS3, and improvements to Ecmascript. In my view, the biggest barrier is user-agent adoption and consistent implementation. Even so, Flash will probably always have its place, like PDF or wave audio, unless someone reinvents a better w̶h̶e̶e̶l̶ mouse trap.

Comment: Last month I was doing a group order. They told me to go to the deli's website to see the specials. I had no clue what they were talking about -- the entire page was plain text, with the background as the only CSS. I check the site on his site, and its a flash box that lets you slideshow-through the menu. WHAT?

Comment: Flash should have stayed in 2010.  It's the third most unstable thing on my box after the Kindle PC reader and my own apps.  The sooner it dies competely, the better.

Comment: I thought I'd never end up on the other side of a circlejerk, but whenever Flash is brought up...

Comment: Flash is now disabled by default in evergreen browsers, I thought.

Comment: @TylerH: Just Firefox for now.

Comment: Agree Flash should had stayed as a platform.  Attempting to do animation in css is kind of ridiculous -- and to even say it can be done in the same level.  ha...

Comment: @BoltClock Also the major mobile browsers don't even allow you to enable flash.

Comment: @Brian Probably good since Flash for mobile hasn't been supported for quite some time now.

Comment: @TylerH I have a flash plugin for my mobile FF browser.  OK, it only works for ~3 seconds before seizing up, but it's there..

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Director of Ad Sales here. Thanks so much for pointing this out. We've paused the campaigns until the client can fix the issue.

Comment: You *really* need something more official to designate who you are.  If I hadn't looked at your profile, I would have wondered if you were trolling me or not.  But anyway, thank you very much for looking into this - I definitely appreciate it!

Comment: @Makoto he's the crocodile... what more official can that become?

Comment: @Makoto How did the profile help you verify that he is who he claims to be? I can also put *Stack Exchange Director of Ad Sales and Operations* into my profile.

Comment: But can you have your profile linked to your picture on the StackExchange team page? http://stackexchange.com/about/team And it's a Gator!

Comment: The client let us know that the issue has been fixed and we are relaunching the campaigns. Please let me know if you happen to see any issues. The remaining flash object is part of a product the client is using called AdSafe (now IntegralAds). They use it, as I understand it, to prevent ad fraud. www.integralads.com/data-metrics/ad-fraud

Comment: @DannyMiller I agree with Makoto. We shouldnt have to spider the Stack Exchange site to verify someones identity

Comment: The presence of a Gator made me seriously question his veracity, for sure...

Comment: @DannyMiller, you've said that you [were working to get a diamond added](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281752/sponsored-links-for-this-tag-box-is-taller-than-its-content/281772#comment137857_281772) :(    You have a very important role. It would avoid confusion and unnecessary discussions when you post official messages.

Comment: @Zanon I agree with you. I tried, but unfortunately, the decision to add a diamond is not mine.

Comment: @DannyMiller, ty for your feedback. That's ok. You have my vote in the next moderator's election! :)

Comment: @Zanon - See [Keep “Employee” on the profile of SE employees on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161197/keep-employee-on-the-profile-of-se-employees-on-meta) and the related posts. Apparently "*sales people*" are not supposed to have diamonds.

Comment: @PM77-1: Can't _"sales people"_ get a coin instead? ;)

Comment: Hey - I'm noticing it's still running with an active campaign.  Is there any information that I can provide to you that'd help you track this down?

Comment: @makoto Are you saying that you are seeing the adsafeprotected.com issue again or just that a Flash ad is running? As per my comment on 7/14 @ 21:06, we do accept Flash for Integral Ads' fraud tracking product.

Comment: It might be the case that it's AdSafeProtected.  I'm noticing the same request pop up.  It's not a Flash advert directly.  It may be the case that this is the acceptable Flash usage as opposed to anything untoward.

Comment: @Makoto Can you provide a screenshot so that we can determine if this is the previous issue or an accepted use?

Comment: As soon as I can identify the advert again, I will.  My browser just crashed, so I lost the tab that it was on.

Comment: Which part would you like a screenshot of?  The advert or the source code in question?

Comment: If you can take a screenshot of both, that would be most helpful.

Comment: We seem to have a new report [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302615/what-should-i-do-when-i-notice-a-flash-tracker-in-an-ad)

Comment: And [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326659/very-slight-possibility-of-malware-or-something?noredirect=1#comment360155_326659)