# Very slight possibility of malware or something?

Tags: bug, advertising, security

Just FWIW, I clicked on a totally ordinary "add comment" link and this appeared,

[image]

Just possibly, could it be due to some ad content or other on the page?

At the time I had just opened the browser fresh (first thing in the morning) and indeed had only gone to SO.

Hope it helps.

(I know zero about security.)

{It goes without saying, it is inconceivable I would run "Flash" on a computer. I never have nor never would install it.}

Comment: Are you sure you were on SO and not a clone site?

Comment: Hi Nathan, of course anything is possible: however, I launched the browser and proceeded straight to SO using my usual menu-bar bookmark; the site perfectly knew[knows] it was[is] me, ie, was actually interacting with my score etc, bringing up messages, checking my bounties, commenting with young mbka (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968839/unity3d-script-losing-audioclip-reference-when-using-addcomponent/37971295?noredirect=1#comment63389437_37971295) etc ... indeed while clicking "comment" as I had done a number of times, the Event happened.  I hope that helps in some way...

Comment: SO does not use Flash in the site at all, and I'm virtually certain SO does not permit Flash in ads either.  This might be something on your end.

Comment: @JoeBlow Are you still getting this?  Did you run a virus/malware scan?  I had only asked about using a clone site as that has come up before.

Comment: hi @NathanOliver - yes, thoroughly scanned for problems.

Comment: We've paused the offending campaign until we're able to reach out to the client and address the issue. Ads shouldn't be using Flash. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: no worries!  it sounds like you founded the ad in question. sorry i wasn't able to be more immediately helpful !

Comment: @JoeBlow Thanks for letting us know about this! The client has removed the offending pixel on their end and we've implemented new creative tags (I'm on the Ad Ops team at SO)

Comment: no worries sorry I am clueless!

Answer (score 0):

based on this,

[Ads are using Flash once again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299158/ads-are-using-flash-once-again)

i'm 95% certain I **probably got an SO an ad which includes Flash**.

1) so, for example if I deliberately go to some site that has flash shit, I get the identical message, absolutely the same

2) my laptops are professionally maintained in a very bare manner for security reasons

3) as i mention, coincidentally i'd just started the computer in the morning, launched the browser, had only the one window open, and the first and only site i overtly went to was SO.

{of course, these days there are billions of redirects and advertisement cross links and stuff going on behind the scenes, but the only page I "went to" was SO.}

hope it helps someone!