# PyCharm ad uses Flash

Tags: support, advertising

As per [Ads are using Flash once again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299158/ads-are-using-flash-once-again), I’ve just noticed another ad that appears to be using Flash (triggering the “Allow http://stackoverflow.com to run ‘Adobe Flash’?” message).

I’ve identified the ad to be the JetBrains PyCharm ad. I also have saved the full URL to the `ad.doubleclick.net` domain if necessary.

[image: Firefox indicating that Flash is being used]

---

Another one: the Dell Mozy ad with that goat.

---

Links to those two ads that are hopefully not too personalized: [PyCharm ad](https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/adi/N366601.1948300STACKOVERFLOW/B9739944.132287376;dc_ver=37.97;dc_eid=40004000;sz=300x250;osdl=1;u_sd=1;dc_adk=2027040026;ord=y0m0p1;click=http%3A%2F%2Fengine.adzerk.net%2Fr%3Fe%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%26s%3DMpWfIv-3cFHiWgP4f3zJTR4n8fg%26url%3D;dc_rfl=1,http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F41921276%2Fpython-3-is-this-a-float-or-a-list$0;xdt=0;crlt=Z1WT*%29egs7;sttr=120;prcl=s?), [Mozy ad](https://ad.doubleclick.net/ddm/adi/N3175.1810601SERVERFAULT.COM/B10820410.144531211;dc_ver=37.97;dc_eid=40004000;sz=300x250;osdl=1;u_sd=1;dc_adk=2027040026;ord=puw6o9;click=http%3A%2F%2Fengine.adzerk.net%2Fr%3Fe%3DeyJhdiI6Nzc3NiwiYXQiOjUsImJ0IjowLCJjbSI6NTI1ODMxLCJjaCI6MTE3OCwiY2siOnt9LCJjciI6MTg2MjI2OCwiZGkiOiIwNzM3Y2FiNGNiNWY0MzhkYjU1YWYwYzAyMWYxZjQ5ZCIsImRtIjoxLCJmYyI6MjIzNTU1NCwiZmwiOjI2ODQwNDcsImlwIjoiODcuMTY0LjI1MC4yMDkiLCJrdyI6ImMjLGpzb24sYXNwLm5ldC13ZWItYXBpLHgtdXNlci1yZWdpc3RlcmVkLHgtdXNlci1oaWdocmVwLHgtY3Jvc3Mtc2l0ZS1zZXJ2ZXJmYXVsdC5jb20iLCJtayI6IngtY3Jvc3Mtc2l0ZS1zZXJ2ZXJmYXVsdC5jb20iLCJudyI6MjIsInBjIjo2LjMsImVjIjo2LjMsInByIjoxNTY3LCJydCI6MiwicmYiOiJodHRwOi8vc3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdy5jb20vIiwic3QiOjgyNzcsInVrIjoidWUxLTU0NTNkNmI1OWJjOTQ5MzVhMDg3OWIyNzRjOGU0MDA0Iiwiem4iOjQ1LCJ0cyI6MTQ4NTc2MTg1NjM2OSwiYmYiOnRydWUsInBuIjoiYWR6ZXJrNzMyMjc4NTM0IiwidXIiOm51bGx9%26s%3DA-Zivo4zFgzPhypD3bJ5K_kXL8o%26url%3D;dc_rfl=1,http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F41930834%2Fjson-format-in-asp-net-web-api$0;xdt=0;crlt=2dx0-2yOqz;sttr=20;prcl=s?).

Comment: Curious, I don't notice this ad running Flash on my machine.

Comment: The ad on its own does not appear to use Flash to display itself—it works fine without, and with Flash enabled it just looks the same. But viewing the ad triggers the “enable Flash” message, so there is *something* inside that uses Flash. I can still reproduce this using yesterday’s ad URL.

Comment: @poke I'm having a difficult time reproducing this one. Can you indulge me and provide a little more information? I, like you, am seeing the ad load without Flash. But the "viewing the ad triggers..." part is the one I'm having a difficult time experiencing. Care to help me help you? :-)

Comment: @stevvve You will need to check this using a browser that blocks Flash by default. Firefox does this for example and trigger said message to prompt you to enable Flash for the site. I think Chrome is doing that soon too but not sure if that landed yet. I’ve added a screenshot to the answer. If you want/need, I can also provide you with the direct URLs to the ads (not sure if they contain any personal tracking information though).

Comment: @poke Yes please re: URLs. I found it in the wild and forced it via live preview and still can't see it. But if you're seeing it is has to be real. URLs should help. Also: thank you for your help thus far, my job would be much harder without you and others like you!

Comment: @stevvve Added links to the question, they are still producing the Flash trigger to me.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it on Firefox 51 on Debian, tried to see if the source code included any reference to flash, and couldn't find it either.

Comment: Just when I wanted to test those links, they're missing... *thanks AdBlock* -_-" Anyway, I couldn't repro it on Chrome 55 (incognito) on Windows 10 with Flash blocked. I could see the ad just fine (just like anyone else), but Chrome didn't prompt that Flash is blocked on those sites.

Comment: Thanks to others for contributing. I want to address this because I don't want Flash issues for you all, but if I can't repro it and it's not happening to everyone, that makes solving the problem *complicated*. I hate to let a post that continues to receive upvotes languish, but I'm currently at a dead-end. I'll keep digging but this one is gonna drop from my focus for a little while.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I cannot reliably reproduce it on multiple machines anymore at this point either. The problem appeared on multiple machines before, but stopped appearing for all but one machine. No idea what’s going on there, but I just have to assume at this point that it’s a detection failure… :/