# Why am I seeing top banner ads on SO? (my rep is greater than 200)

Tags: support, advertising

Is this a current bug, or did SO change the policy of ad suppression?[image: Stackato ad]

Comment: Nope, it's not a bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msdn , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel

Comment: Related (duplicate?) [Is it possible for high rep users to get rid of “Sponsored links for this tag”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281521/is-it-possible-for-high-rep-users-to-get-rid-of-sponsored-links-for-this-tag)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reduced ads privilege only covers the leaderboard banners that appear when browsing questions:

> [image: Leaderboard Ads]

The sponsored links on a tag's page, as well as the small box ads in the right side-bar, are visible to all users regardless of reputation.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect browsing to be different than the landing page. Wonder why I didn't notice it before?