# Sponsored links for tag home pages? Are you serious?

Tags: discussion, design

I just came over this with my favorite tag:

[image]

Eeeeeek, please remove that *"feature"*. It costs too much screen space for the newest question list, and distracts too much.

If at all move that to the side bar.

Comment: I think this is fine for me, on one or the the other way, SE needs to make money. However, maybe we could remove it on a [milestone](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I understand that tey need to get some revenue. But just frickin' up the UI in such bad way won't be helpful for that. At least I won't give that a single click anyways. That's just annoying.

Comment: This has been in place for a loooooong time... Also, this sounds a lot like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281521/215552....

Comment: @Mike I never met that before (unless I was banned). Did that depend on rep for now?

Comment: For anyone who can't see them, this is blocked with an adblocker like AdBlockPlus or uBlock.

Comment: These should be in the sidebar. As it is, it's annoying enough that a significant number of people will just remove it via user script/ad blocker. If it's in the sidebar, people will still see it, but, for many, it will be below the threshold for actively doing something about it.

Comment: @Makyen Seemed to be a small hiccup. Everything's SNAFU again now.

Comment: I'm not sure. It would be nice to hear from @stevvve about what happened with [his answer to that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281616/215552)...

Comment: If it's a favorite tag, why not add it as a tab? It looks like having it as a tab, instead of filtering questing by the tag, hides the sponsor thing. (If you click on any of the links and then hit the back button, it'll go back to behaving like it's just a filter but if you just go to your tab you won't see sponsored links.)

Comment: I don't have an ad blocker installed, and I don't see any sponsorship on the [c++] tag. So I'm not sure what the screenshot is about. However, I would also be a bit distressed if some random, unrelated organization decided to sponsor the C++ tag, and if that plastered a bunch of nonsense on my screen.