# What does reviewing low quality posts get me?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

What does reviewing low quality posts get me? Please explain to me why spend time doing this for you.

Comment: The same as any other reviews: 1/ You are keeping bad questions and answers off the site, 2/ There are review badges to be earned ...

Comment: It gives you badges for 1, 250 and 1000 reviews :) Joke aside, you're helping the community to clean up bad questions and answers, that's for most reviewers reason enough to do it. I'm also not sure if "doing this for **you**" is the best term. You're doing it for the greater good, not for a specific group of users.

Comment: What does answering questions get you? Or suggesting edits? Or posting comments? Or voting?

Comment: Nothing. Stop doing them. If you have to ask the question...

Comment: I mean...... Some volunteers gave you time in the past and that helped you, no? Why not pay it forward?

Comment: The real question: why spending time on the site after all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Aside from a few pixels in your profile (in the form of few review-related badges), it doesn't provide you any direct benefit. By reviewing, you are intentionally exposing yourself to some of the lowest quality and least valuable content on the site. Many people find it discouraging and stop reviewing altogether.

However, Stack Overflow wouldn't be the valuable resource it is today without people who help in the moderation. The main difference between Stack Overflow and other programming forums is the strict nature of the rules here and the willingness of the users to uphold them, such as aggregating information in one place by closing duplicates, removing unhelpful off-topic posts, and optimizing for helpful content over chat and other distractions.

Reviewing is one of the ways that moderation takes place. Some people review because they want to somehow [say "thank you" to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269681/how-can-i-thank-this-website). Others review because they like to see numbers go up and earn badges. But I think the most common reason for reviewing is because people value the focus of Stack Overflow, and want to make sure it stays the amazingly useful resource that it has been for the last decade, and that it doesn't degrade under the onslaught of low quality posts and spam.

Comment: The reason I intentionally expose myself to the 'lowest quality and least valuable content on the site' is so I can be happy in the knowledge that I am contributing to deleting it.