# What do I do about being harassed by users outside of Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, offensive, harassment

Earlier I voted to close a question on Stack Overflow (the user was ranting about the site). This person proceeded to track down an email address via my publicly listed website and email me regarding my close vote. Presumably he attempted to do this to other users as well.

I won't name the user, because I'm not sure what the policy is on doing so (unless a moderator wants to contact me about it).

I'm a little curious if there has been a situation like this before. On one hand I think people on the site should own their close votes, on the other hand I don't think anyone deserves offsite harassment for it.

Make close votes anonymous? / Show close votes only to users who have X number of reputation points?

I would hate for threats of harassment to discourage people from closing low quality questions.

Certainly I could remove my contact information from my site or not post my site on Stack Overflow, I'd prefer not to do that as I want people to contact me about my consulting services.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Addressing some specific things that have been brought up here:

*Does one email rise to the level of "harassment"?*

No of course not. I was attempting to phrase the question to have a general discussion should the contact rise to that level. To help me or perhaps others in the future. Even one nasty email can cause someone to think twice about participating in moderation.  I apologize for using the word "harassment" as it seems that has distracted from the intent.

*Why didn't you post the content of the email?*

I did not feel it necessary to out the particular user or post the content of his email as I felt a general discussion was appropriate. The email was offensive and highly inappropriate but it did not contain any sort of specific threats. Given the context of the original post on Stack Overflow and the person's digging up of an email to contact me made me feel he might continue contacting me.

*Why would you post a way for contact you if you don't want to be contacted on the Internet?*

My email address isn't on my profile, it's on my consulting website which is linked on my profile. The website is there for people to contact me about my consulting services but if anyone on SO found it and had questions about anything I posted on the site I'd be happy to respond if I have the time. Polite contact isn't a problem.

*A bunch of your contact info is out there on domains etc.*

Thanks to those who pointed that out. I made my domain registration private. I'll also be removing the email address in question and providing a contact form instead.

Comment: Duplicate, but I won't close because this deserves its own attention: [What do I do about receiving an offensive email from another user on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261941/456814).

Comment: Related: [What do you do when someone calls you personally about an answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261178/456814).

Comment: My apologies. I searched for related questions and didn't find that one.

Comment: Close votes, just like delete votes, are transparent, to help identify and deter abuse. However, only 10k+ users can see who cast delete votes (unless your own post is deleted), so I don't see why we couldn't also allow only 3k+ users, for example, to see who cast close votes. Then again, if you can see the delete votes on your own deleted posts, then why shouldn't you also be able to see the close votes on your own posts?

Comment: For example, what is a high-rep user suddenly starts closing and deleting all of your questions? If could be an instance of abuse, or it could just be a case of normal unbiased post cleanup, but without knowing who is doing it, how could you even bring the issue up on Meta or to the mods?

Comment: Close votes require reasons. Perhaps posting the reason with a link to Meta so the user could ask for clarification. I'm torn though, because in general I agree it should be transparent.

Comment: So the question you're asking is how to stop people from contacting you **unless** they want to contact you for consulting/contracting, in which case it's OK? If you choose to publish your contact information in your profile, you're offering the ability for *anyone* to contact you; you don't get to pick and choose what purposes for which they're allowed to use that contact info. If you don't want people to contact you, don't publish contact info. (You're calling your phone company and saying "I have a published phone number, but I don't want everyone to be able to see it in the book.")

Comment: @KenWhite - no its more akin to calling the police when someone uses my published phone number for purposes of harassment. Which is something there are real-life consequences for. I'm not asking how to control why someone is contacting me. I'm asking how this problem has been dealt with in the past. Should this particular user be flagged or banned? And how the features might be changed such that we maintain transparency while offering some sort of protection against this sort of thing.

Comment: To clarify I have no issue with people contacting me. Otherwise I wouldn't post a way for them to do so. I have an issue with harassment.

Comment: No, it's nowhere near the same thing. I'm not saying it's appropriate for the user to contact you; I'm saying that's a risk you expose yourself to by providing that contact information in your profile and then taking public actions on internet sites (including SO). You don't have to read or respond to any email, and a single contact from the user is nowhere akin to "harassment", any more than a single call to your home phone number would be. (Call the police because you receive a single phone call from someone who says "I don't like you", and see what response you get.)

Comment: While I don't think this user is any threat to me (he's likely not even in the same country) the content of the email and the fact that he went through at least three layers to find my contact info and likely the contact info of others makes me believe its worthy of discussion.

Comment: @Cfreak - I don't think I've ever been harassed, but I have been called nasty names :) I think this post probably adds fuel to the fire by satisfying the person's [perverted?] needs. You should probably ignore him/her. They will flare up a little bit more when they see its not getting the desired reaction. Then they will move on to another target (maybe me next time ;).

Comment: Looks like you didn't opt for whois privacy on your domain either, you'd be better off changing your profile website to `localhost` like us sensible people. ;)

Comment: Frankly, I think it's probably best to not have your email address or other easily-identifiable info in your profile.  You never can tell when some nutcase is going to make you his "project".  Yes, they can usually track you down some other way if they really want to, but likely they'll get distracted before that happens and go off and harass someone else.

Comment: Growing a thicker skin helps. Its the interenet, this happens all the time.

Comment: Hmm.. The only time I have ever gone out of network to communicate with someone is when I thanked them on twitter for providing details above and beyond their initial one line answer. I cannot even think of a valid reason to go out of network for anything else.

Comment: Wow lots of victim blaming going on here.

Comment: I once made the mistake of friending/following somebody on FB and LinkedIn who replaced me at a contract of mine.  He stalked me all that evening until I was getting emails from him at my personal account.  I simply contacted the company I formerly contracted for additionally informing them I suspecting him of using the laptop they issued to him for this purpose.  They were a company that prided themselves on their Christian values, and I'm pretty sure he lost his job because of it.

Answer (score 153):

I hope you didn't reply. Switching to ***Ignore Mode*** is the best response.

[image]

It's not like you have to answer the email (or phone calls for that matter.  That's why I have caller ID).

Comment: This. The best revenge is making sure jackasses don't succeed in wasting your time.

Comment: No I didn't reply. Marked it as spam.

Comment: Boy, I sure look young in that picture. Where'd you dig that up?

Comment: This (solid) advice also applies pretty successfully to most other fields in life and not just Stack Overflow. You often get to choose the arguments you participate in. It's a shame a lot of people don't recognize this.

Comment: _runs to warn [banana](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1206300/banana) about @Tim_

Comment: first thing to do when seeing a random email from person I don't know? spam.

Comment: @pnuts done with that noise... even still.. harrassment goes in the trash. and moving on.

Comment: I would reply, and troll them into making actionable threats against you. But.... I'm a dick.

Comment: http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/011/5/b/don__t_feed_the_troll___by_blag001-d5r7e47.png

Comment: This doesn't address the concerns of OP at all, added my own answer

Answer (score 77):

As a general rule, you should follow [Robert's advice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267851/what-do-i-do-about-being-harassed-by-users-outside-of-stack-overflow/267860#267860) - feeding into this sort of nonsense just encourages it.

If someone gets under your skin (death threats, etc), report it - contact us via community-support@stackoverflow.com with the emails as attachments. We probably can't *do* much about it, but we'll do what we can to back you up. Again though, *don't respond.*

Comment: Thank you. I don't believe the contact rises to that level but if this person persists then I know where to send it. I did not respond, so hopefully that will be the end of it.

Comment: Well, actually if it escalates to death threats, I am pretty sure you can bring the matter before the law; I suppose it requires identifying the country the user lives in (but StackOverflow would have the user's IP, so might help here) and bringing the matter to that country's justice system...

Comment: Death threats need to be reported to law enforcement agencies.

Answer (score 3):

I have never been contacted in anger, but a number of users have contacted me directly via email or Twitter to ask for help with a particular problem because they've seen an answer I posted to something related. Honestly, in many ways, this still sucks. Even though the correspondence is cordial, it's a bit too *personal*. However, I, like the the OP, made myself available by using my real name and linking to my blog through my profile. With that, comes things like this, and even if it escalates to the point of harrassment, it's not really the responsibility of Stack Overflow to do *anything*. Once it leaves this site, it's outside both this site's influence and concern.

That said, it may at some point be worthwhile to investigate some level of privacy controls for user profiles. I'm not sure how many users would actually want to hide things like links to their personal websites, but I could see a use case for wanting to put some threshold on it, so that not everyone who comes in and creates an account can see all the information on your profile. That still doesn't prevent the user from still finding you in other ways. If you use your real name here, your site will very easily come up with a Google search, and you're right back in the same boat. However, I can't see anything more that Stack Overflow could ever do than that.

Comment: [What do you do when someone calls you personally about an answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261178/456814).

Comment: @Cupcake: Thanks, but I mentioned my personal experience mostly for illustrative purposes. It's not something I'm truly concerned about. It's a little intrusive at times, but not enough that I'm motivated to do something about it.

Answer (score -1):

The advise given by the diamonds here are useless and completely ignores the problem. I propose a change where **only logged in users with a reputation above X can see who closed a question**, maybe with the addition *if the question was asked by a user with rep below X*.

This will keep the transparency for the most part, but at the same time allow users to review close votes from low rep users without the fear of harassment.

Comment: [I've talked about this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267851/what-do-i-do-about-being-harassed-by-users-outside-of-stack-overflow#comment73110_267851). Also see the comment below it.

Comment: @Matsemann: If you want to make a suggestion for a policy change, don't put it as an answer to the question "What do **I** do ...". Make a new post, and tag it `[feature-request]`. Do link to this question, though.