# Ban users from editing when their approved/rejected ratio is low

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, edit-ban

From what I have been able to find on [how suggested edits work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), users get a 7 day ban from editing privileges when their [rejected edits the **last 7 days** considerably outweigh their approved edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337):

```
rejectedLast7Days - (approvedLast7Days / 3) >= 5
```

Which means that users can submit 5 bad edits every week without any approved. This might fit most users, but some users are simply incredibly bad at suggesting edits, and they should in my opinion not be allowed to suggest 5 bad edits before being banned. For example, [this simple query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/215719/find-users-with-low-accepted-approved-edits?MinimumRejected=10) shows that some users have **as many as <s>20</s> 15 rejected edits without a single one approved**.

Therefore, I suggest that the total approved/rejected ratio for a user is taken into account when deciding how many rejected edits are allowed before a ban:

```
percentageApproved = approvedTotal / (rejectedTotal + approvedTotal)

rejectedLast7Days - (approvedLast7Days / 3) >= (4 * percentageApproved) + 1
```

**Examples:**

- User 1999182 has 15 rejected and 0 accepted edits. 1 rejected edit
  without any approved would lead to a ban (`4 * (0/15) + 1 = 1 <= 1`).
- User 538613 has 76 rejected and 37 accepted edits. 2 rejected edits without any approved would lead to a ban (`4 * (37/113) + 1 = 1.3 <= 2`).
- User 2801037 has 5 rejected and 131 accepted edits. As now, 5 rejected edits without any approved would lead to a ban (`4 * (5/136) + 1 = 4.85 <= 5`).

Comment: I wouldn't go with rejected edits but rejection flag from reviewer. Too many robo-reviewers approve everything. So going with flags, bad editors would be banned regardless of the bad edit being approved or not.

Comment: [@Banana: beware of Tim](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267851/what-do-i-do-about-being-harassed-by-users-outside-of-stack-overflow#comment73534_267860)

Comment: Would it make sense to also incorporate reputation into the mix? In the sense that if you constantly get rejected edits (or a slew of rejected edits in the past 7 days), then you lose some bit of reputation? I feel like that would do two things: 1) Cause bad editors to eventually lose their privilege (which they haven't been putting to good use), and 2) Prevent users from editing without having put thought into the edit (which is what I presume results in rejected edits).

Comment: @Zhouster If approved is +2, rejected should be -2.

Comment: @bjb568 Hmmm, I err on the side of being a little more lenient. So you would only start losing reputation after you hit that threshold of many more rejected edits than approved edits. Though, I guess in that case, if you have a slew of rejected edits, you would need to have a sort of incremental loss of reputation (i.e. -2, -4, -6, -8). At least this way, you prevent people from gaining reputation for the sake of rep (or so I would hope).

Comment: I think you might be able to keep track of the total amount until the first ban. Once punishment has been levied, time's been served, we have to consider that user rehabilitated. We can take into account previous bans to determine the severity of punishment on subsequent bans as opposed to "holding grudges". This would be like a 3 strike rule.

Comment: @Zhouster I actually suggested removing rep for rejected edits a while ago: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267311/removing-reputation-for-rejected-edits

Comment: Maybe a rolling ban size? So as your ratio gets worse (or does not improve with more edit suggestions), bump the ban window. Another option would be requiring more reviewers for people with poor edit review ratios, to try and avoid robo-reviewers.

Comment: @thegrinner I like the thought of having more reviewers for people with poor edit history. I would also think pulling in those with better edit histories (and maybe rep) towards these poorer edits would help. So sort of like recommending poor editor's edits to the better editors to review.

Comment: @Zhouster So my reward for good contributions and edits is to deal with *more* crap than everyone else? ;)

Comment: @TavianBarnes Haha, exactly! But look at it this way, maybe you'll get some good laughs out of the sheer ridiculousness of some edits. :D All jokes aside, this is true, but I feel like people like you are the best ones to deal with said crap. :X It's kind of like "parents are the least appreciated job", even though they are the most important.

Comment: Reviews are not always correct. Bad edits get approved and good edits get rejected. There is a behavior pattern called robo-reviewing, which leads to a lot of false-positives.

Comment: It belongs to meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Banana: no, this is perfectly on-topic here too.