# What do you do if a user sends an aggressive message to you off-site after you have downvoted their post?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, etiquette, downvote-reason, harassment

Some time ago, I have been tracked down online about a down vote I have made.

It was a simple question, and the answer of the guy X have provided was pretty wrong one. So I downvoted it, left a comment and went away.

Then he responded:

[image: first response]

Since this is an obvious [someone is wrong on the internet](http://xkcd.com/386/) case, I didn't even bother to extend the discussion and went away with my business. But still, I have reviewed his answer in more detail and found out that it has way more errors than I have noticed the first time. But didn't say anything in order to stop the conversation.

After some time, he found me on twitter and mentioned me with a similar message, asking me to "retreat my downvote". I have ignored the message and blocked him from Twitter.

It ended there, he didn't follow up with anything else, and the downvote is still there, too. I am pretty sure that I have done the right thing, but could it be handled differently?

Also, when is it against (if ever) SO/SE policy to ban users for these types of harassments?

Comment: Related: many posts under the [meta-tag:downvote-reason], [meta-tag:etiquette], and [meta-tag:harassment] tags.

Comment: This kind of thing is beginning to occur with *horrifying* frequency. And these are just the people who report it on Meta. I shudder to think at all the others who just *deal* with it silently.

Comment: Oh, and you can't even retract your downvote even if you want to. The answerer never bothered to edit his answer.

Comment: @CodyGray Stack Overflow has 3.4 million registered users. At that scale, is it really that surprising that we hear of these sort of things so often?

Comment: Well…yes. Gosh, I hope with that logic you aren't suggesting that we should start expecting some of our users to be murdered by other users. It takes a special type of person to *track someone down* who has answered their question online and stalk or harass them. Perhaps naïvely, I hope that those people are rare, even when you've got 3.4 million of 'em. Anyway, I said I was distressed/horrified at the frequency, not necessarily surprised.

Comment: had it happen in an MMO, the stalker was a former CSR of the company who'd somehow retained his access to customer data. Got death threats to my RL address, got my property vandalised. Police were powerless, not only nearly impossible to prove but how do you identify someone who you know only by a pseudonym... More than that the mail came from Australia we never found out. Ended when the guy got bored of the game and quit it, some 2 years later.

Comment: @mehow - don't worry - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me

Comment: lol, I will do! Fedex express - your tasty koala is only 48 hours away.

Comment: IMHO, downvotes are for really bad answers. Commenting on the cases that it doesn't work is encouraged but a downvote is not needed in that case

Comment: @mehow "Stalking is unwanted or obsessive attention by an individual or group toward another person. Stalking behaviors are related to harassment and intimidation and may include following the victim in person or monitoring them." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalking

Comment: Just because I put my twitter handle to my profile and my blog, doesn't mean I let random people to reach me out to give some orders.

Comment: This is why I never justify my downvotes. If do it anonymously if it were possible.

Comment: Insightful, @JuanMendes; There should be a bigger cost to rep if you choose to downvote.  People _should_ consider just commenting... or even _editing_ the problem post if the information provided is really off. @UmurKontaci, actually just signing up for a Twitter handle allows interaction, pos and neg. From the [Twitter TOS](https://twitter.com/tos):  You understand that by using the Services, you may be exposed to Content that might be offensive, harmful, inaccurate or otherwise inappropriate...

Comment: I don't believe that reaching out to you on your publicly linked account is considered stalking. Seems like he wants to continue the conversation. If he had found your unlinked facebook or reddit or whatever and continued to harass you, I think there'd be a problem. Using the term "stalk" here devalues it too much.

Comment: I would support larger penalties for down voting *if* there were some guarantee that I would eventually retrieve the reputation for justified down votes. AFAIK, the reputation is only returned if the downvoted item is deleted.

Comment: Isn't _stalking_ what 'social networking' was invented for?

Comment: Unless he's at your front door; ignore him. Let him spend the energy, not you; *be the wiser*. Someone who's going to go to those lengths, should seek professional help, and fast.

Comment: Oh, the title changed from "stalks you offsite" to "sends an aggressive message" and I got excited for a moment cause I thought we had another rant...

Comment: @CodyGray murder is very different from the simple act of Googling a name

Comment: So far for downvoting somebody's answer I had just retaliation downvotes on my old questions (since they are free).  I guess I was getting off easy.

Comment: I hate it when the downvotes retreat.  They should advance!  attack!

Comment: @CodyGray: It's a simple numbers game.  Even if it's only 0.1% of people who are like that, 0.1% of 3.4 million is 3,400 stalkers on SE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Abusive/aggressive users taking it outside of Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277134/abusive-aggressive-users-taking-it-outside-of-stack-overflow)

Comment: Hello @JasonC, the linked question is closed as a duplicate and redirects to here.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

When a user contacts you ***the first time*** outside of Stack Overflow about a downvote, you may choose to ignore it, as you have already done.

If, however, the user ***persists*** in contacting you about it through other channels, then flag the user's post for moderator attention, using the Other flag, and explain that this user has been nagging you both on and off Stack Overflow about your downvote on his or her post.

The moderators will probably either give the user a warning, or a suspension, in particularly egregious cases or repeat offenses.

**Keep in mind, however**, that there's only so much moderators can do to try to influence a user to stop nagging or harassing you off-site. They're not the internet police. They only have influence over the Stack Exchange network itself, not Twitter, nor your phone provider, etc.

#### See Also

- [Yet another offensive email from another new user on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268123/yet-another-offensive-email-from-another-new-user-on-stack-overflow/268127#268127)
- [What do I do about being harassed by users outside of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267851/what-do-i-do-about-being-harassed-by-users-outside-of-stack-overflow/267862#267862)

Comment: +1 for **Tips for leaving explanations for downvotes**

Comment: I think the better advice is comment, then come back later and downvote. That gives the poster a chance to read the comment and fix the answer, and possibly negate the need for the downvote before it's given.

Comment: I find the tips both valuable and disturbing. It is valuable because, you know, it will help so nobody will get angry with you; but it is also disturbing because I don't want to approach anyone as if they are serial killers.

Comment: @UmurKontacı: Serial killers only attack a small fraction of their acquaintances.

Comment: I'd say this kind of harrassment is so rare that we do not need to recommend to people not owning up to their downvotes.

Comment: @halfer spoken like someone who's never been revenge downvoted before `:P`

Comment: @Cupcake: Do you honestly care about being revenge-downvoted?

Comment: I have received revenge dvotes, but if I get more than a couple in one go, I'll report them a couple of days later if the reverser script doesn't kick in. FWIW I don't suggest that all downvotes are accompanied with a "It was me!" - just that it is good to explain what is bad about a post. If that means someone figures out it was me, that's fine - I'll usually note a `-1` anyway.

Comment: @tmyklebu I care enough about that and harassment to not casually explain to someone that I've just downvoted them because they posted a bad answer.

Comment: @Cupcake: Well, I try to pull out "I downvoted/VTC'd your answer because your answer sucks" only once reason has failed---once I've given a more useful explanation and seen it fall on deaf ears.  Never really been bothered over either the useful explanations or the less detailed explanations beyond SO.  Even if you do care about reputation, though, revenge-downvotes make such a tiny dent that I can't see why it'd ruffle your feathers.

Comment: _You can say something like: I didn't downvote, but blah blah blah..._ Now I know how to identify my downvoters, so I can stalk them B)

Comment: I disagree with this answer, because I think it should be safe common practice to leave a comment when downvoting. Considering this point of view, I think it's only fair to confess that I downvoted this answer too. Please don't stalk me. :-

Comment: I find it mind boggling that you would suggest that you employ dishonest tactics with downvoting. If you downvote and leave a comment about the reasons then you either mention it or not, but don't say _"I didn't downvote, but..."_ if you actually did downvote. It is dishonest and unethical.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel what difference does it make to the author being downvoted if someone downvotes and either doesn't mention it, or says that they didn't? At the end of the day, a post is still downvoted and a comment explaining the reason for it is left for the author to improve. Why give some random, emotionally immature person a reason to go stalk and harass you?

Comment: @Cupcake It is not about the author, it is about being dishonest and unethical. It might sound idealistic, but I believe that we should hold ourselves to a higher moral standard.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel fair enough...just call me a pragmatist, then `:P`

Comment: Another tip: Google be danged, people should stop making accounts with their real names. For instance, how could I ever stalk someone I only know as "Cupcake" even if I wanted to?

Comment: @alcalde don't look at my SO profile.

Comment: @alcalde I think I'm the only one world wide with my nickname. I think I'm much easier to track down by my nick than by my real name. :)

Answer (score 4):

Being stalked on Twitter or Facebook is very annoying. The best way to deal with this is usually just to ignore it as much as possible and don't reply or get into a discussion. This will usually just ignite the fire even more. So I think you handled this just right.

Of course, you *can* notify the moderators as Cupcake suggested. That will probably result in a warning for the user and possibly a replenishment of the points you have lost due to revenge downvotes. But the mods won't be able to help you on Twitter, so you are on your own there. Nevertheless, I think it should be doable to just ignore people on Twitter, so that shouldn't be a reason not to downvote.

As for downvoting and making that public, I think this should be common practice. Downvotes are an integral part of the voting system on Stack Overflow. My feeling is that if more people would leave a comment on downvotes, the chances of flame wars, revenge downvoting and harassing would be much smaller.
If you don't downvote, don't leave a comment, or try to hide the fact that you downvoted, then it will become increasingly difficult for others as well to be openly critical and the bad guys will eventually win.

So I'm asking you to keep downvoting when appropriate, and leave a comment if it feels right. Report any abusive behavior, and risk losing a couple of points. Be a martyr for Stack Overflow and let the world know that downvoting is a right, no a duty, that should not just be given up.

Comment: *Moderators can give out reputation in certain circumstances?* Never knew that.

Comment: Sometimes I see rep changes with the reason "User was removed". So I don't think mods will actively give out reputation, but the system seems to undo reputation changes that were caused by a user that was removed.

Comment: Perhaps they send a request to the developers who access the database and apply the reputation change manually?

Comment: Could be. Honestly, I don't know *how* it works. I just know it works. :)

Comment: For the record, for anyone who comes across this later: it's not true. Moderators can't give out or take away reputation, except by normal voting, same as everybody else. (Exception: a few moderation actions affect reputation as a side effect, e.g. suspending an account sets their rep to 1.)

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks for clearing that up. I didn't actually think moderators could assign or take away reputation explicitly, but only as an implicit result of other actions. But I wasn't sure about this.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this is why [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook) doesn't have a dislike button.

But I think it's actually better to discuss the downvote with the person (on Stack Overflow). They'll probably calm down just talking about it, and then they may even realise their mistake and update their answer.

Your question was more about what to do after this stage; being harassed isn't fun, but ignoring/blocking usually works.

In fact I've been harassed before (through eBay), and I wasn't sure what to do because this man actually had my family address (more worried about them than myself), so I contacted the police and they advised me to either change my number or block the man's number, and if he turns up at my front door then dial the police emergency line and they can deal with him then.

In the end I just blocked his number and then it stopped.

Answer (score -2):

This happens in real life, too.

The solution is not to "call the police" but to ignore it. It will stop.

Comment: But if it *doesn't* stop...will you still not flag a mod about it?

Comment: +1 - don't feed the troll. Not even through a mod.

Answer (score -13):

One message to a contact address publicly listed on your account is not what I would call "stalking." It seems to be an appropriate use of contact information in my opinion.

If a Stack Exchange user does not want his contact information used then why did he put it into his profile?

Comment: It's not about "where did he get my twitter handle", it is about "reaching me out about a downvote and ordering me things". How come giving orders to random people on the internet is an appropriate use of information.

Comment: @UmurKontaci - an order is something that only a person who you accept to be in a position of superiority can give. If I order you to dye your hair purple I expect you to ignore it - I am not in a position to order you to do anything. Ordering without power is delusional - feel a small amount of pity and move on.

Comment: @Zan, the OP *does not publish his Twitter handle*.  So you are inventing a strawman since it is clear that the barbarian googled his name to unearth that info.

Comment: @KirkWoll - I would say that *indirectly* he does. His SO profile links to his GitHub. GitHub page lists personal web-site that publishes his Twitter handle. No googling was required.

Comment: @PM77-1, that logic is absurd.  If it's not on your SO profile, it's not public for SO users.

Comment: @@KirkWoll  - I do not have any logic. I just pointed out that OP's info can be found without much effort.  I'm not saying it's his fault or anything. He's a victim here.  Just in our super-connected age such things are virtually public.