# Abusive/aggressive users taking it outside of Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, etiquette, offensive, harassment

I know that the powers of Stack Overflow moderators and administrators are limited to within Stack Overflow, but what happens in a situation where a user is clearly being argumentative and abusive to another user, and upon receiving warnings, flags and comment deletions, they then take matters outside of Stack Overflow, to something like Twitter, to abuse the other person.

Again, I appreciate that the question is strange, but this has happened to me, and I'm sure it's not at all that uncommon. I was just wondering if some sort of action should be taken on here, as I can't find a way to flag a user.

Comment: [Suggested reading](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261941/what-do-i-do-about-receiving-an-offensive-email-from-another-user-on-stack-overf)

Comment: @bluefeet excellent thank you, I did try searching but couldn't find it.

Comment: You should be using the tools of that external medium to deal with inappropriate behavior in that medium.

Comment: @ollieread I'd suggest stop engaging the user.

Comment: I was more curious regarding processes here as I have seen this happen a few times to other users, which can cause a good amount of distress. I'm not particularly affected by the individual, but others may be in their situations.

Comment: While I'm more than happy to give as good as I get on medium such as Twitter, there are certain lines. Besides that, such behaviour isn't conducive to the goals of this community.

Comment: @ollieread - as a site (diamond) mod I used to get a few emails and Twitter contacts from users who weren't best pleased they'd been moderated. Most quickly get bored after a day or two after being blocked on Twitter and ignoring their emails.

Comment: @shabeer90 please read the description for the 'amd' tag.  It's not about the company Advanced Micro Devices so should not be used for that.

Comment: This is an excellent question and it's good that you've asked it. It's not strange and it has happened to users before. Contacting the team is the right thing to do.

Comment: I'm pretty much a jerk, I never get people bothering me outside of Stack Overflow. I must not be trying hard enough.

Comment: Ahaha all I did was point out that he shouldn't have explained how to do something because it was horrendously insecure.

Comment: Just let me know and I'll take care of them.

Comment: I have voted to reopen on the following grounds: 1) I believe this question is simpler, more generic, and more useful in general than the linked duplicate, and 2) The answers on the linked duplicate are extremely specific to that case and the actions to be taken are not immediately clear. The linked post is good reading and is relevant, but I do not believe that a detailed story about abusive emails, as heartwarming as it is, is appropriate as the "canonical" reference question for this topic. (In fact, I would argue that the linked one be marked as a duplicate of this one, despite timing.)

Comment: The second duplicate says that it's a duplicate of this one and this one says it's a duplicate of the second.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You could [contact the SE team directly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) if you think there is some [action they can take](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277137/616460). Regardless:

1. **Ignore them; stop responding or otherwise engaging.**
2. Use whatever abuse management tools are available to you elsewhere (e.g. blocking / reporting users on twitter, email inbox filters, etc).
3. Keep on truckin'.

Comment: I would also recommending outing them in public on twitter, but that may backfire.

Comment: @MikeCole That serves no purpose other than perhaps some misguided self-validation (in which case some healthy reflection on your criteria for maintaining your self-image may be in order). It also serves to unnecessarily fuel the fire. The high road is always the better road.

Comment: #1 is the mature thing to do.  Let the baby have their soapbox, and get on with your life.

Answer (score 68):

This sort of behavior is not tolerated.

If a user exhibits bad behavior on Stack Overflow, we'll take our normal action: Warn/Suspend as appropriate.

We also do the same thing if a user is abusive to another user outside of Stack Overflow *for something that happened on Stack Overflow*.

If this happens to you, flag the source post that started the issue (whether it be a comment or an actual post) with a custom flag that explains what's going on. Include links to the external bad behavior.

If it's an email, forward the email to `team@stackoverflow.com` with the same information.

As moderators, we can handle everything outside of email bad behavior; mostly because we don't have an email address where we receive email.  The Community Team will be able to handle instances where a user has been abusive in an email.

Comment: As Tim Post said: ***What goes on in Stack Overflow stays in Stack Overflow.***

Comment: Thank you for the tip regarding mailing to team@stackoverflow. I have been trolled by another SO user lately: in the past couple of days, he has been downvoting my only two questions and a couple of OK answers (I know that downvoting is anonymous, but evenso I know who has cast those downvotes). I am currently writing a book and I was planning to mention this person as an example of a troll that spoils the fun of answering questions. Based on your answer, I've reconsidered and I've sent a mail to the SO team instead.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: "I know who has cast those downvotes" *know* is a strong word.

Comment: Well, let's rephrase that to "I have indications as to who has cast those downvotes" ;-) Take for instance this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12604171/data-encoding-when-submitting-a-pdf-form-using-acroform-technology I have brought this question to the ISO committee responsible for the PDF spec and they have confirmed that I discovered a flaw in ISO-32000-1. My proposed fix was accepted for insertion in the upcoming ISO-32000-2 standard. What could be the rationale to downvote such a question, other than trolling?