# User frustrated with moderation on their post

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, close-reasons

This meta post is going to be a little different than the norm. This morning, I received an email to my professional account from a user who posted a question on Stack Overflow, only to have their question put on hold and then edited several times in a way they didn't understand. I could just reply to his email, but I felt that this probably happens more than we know and perhaps it could be beneficial to others in the future. It also allows the community to have a discussion about the issue or chime in on any points I might have missed.

The email I received this morning goes like this:

*(I'm purposely leaving his name out of this post, but emailing him the link to it. If he would like to chime in with his comments, I'll let him make that determination.)*

> Hi Michael
>
> I’m referring to the following post:
>   [Application freeze C# .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988236/application-freeze-c-sharp-net)
>
> I discovered that several people, inclduding you, have degraded my
>   original post on stackexchange several times. I find this extremely
>   strange and - to be honest - a bit self-righteous too. Why won’t you
>   just let professionals ask other professionals their questions? Would
>   it hurt you in any way to leave a post as is instead of altering it or
>   putting it on hold just because you don’t see an immediate solution to
>   the described problem? Maybe others have exactly the insight I need on
>   the subject. Isn’t that the idea of stack exchange?
>
> If you go back to my original post that was put on hold, you’ll see
>   TONS of Information in there about the issue. In fact, there was as
>   much and precise info in there as I possibly could gaher. Have you
>   never ever had an extremely strange issue in programming that you just
>   couldn’t get a grasp on and clinged for help?
>
> And by the way: After intensive research on similar matters, I have
>   found out that my question was completely legit and was asked before
>   in different words:
>   [C# application keeps freezing on remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103250/c-sharp-application-keeps-freezing-on-remote)
>
> So the symptoms I described carefully could have been answered by
>   someone with the required knowledge. I find it quite ironic to see how
>   a group of super-professionals degraded my question as “not beneficial
>   to other” while it was answered on the same plattform in a different
>   post with different wording.
>
> Best regards

I am going to respond to his email and point him here, but I am also going to reply here and (hopefully) allow others to chime in.

Comment: Beats the email I had where I was threatened with bodily harm.

Comment: That's still a good email, better than the usual offensive hate mail some users were unlucky enough to receive.

Comment: Granted it is the *OP* of the closed question who edited the question from list of symptoms to a comment on the closure + a terse question, but I would have reverted the post to its previous version rather than just remove the noisy comment. This is as far as editing goes. As far as the closure goes, I'm not disagreeing with those who voted to close.

Comment: Agreed with @Louis that this is fairly important: your Meta post and the author's email make it sound like someone else edited the question dramatically (and "several times"). You could perhaps be a little more clear that the OP was the primary editor.

Comment: The link to the question is dead.

Comment: @Flavius The question is deleted, so you'll bee the required reputation to be able to see it.

Comment: @Louis I agree with you, that smarter move on my part would have been to roll back the changes.

Comment: A poster asks a great question, gets mistreated in an all-too-common way by the community, sends you a well written, more than fair under the circumstances letter on the subject... and you come here to **complain** about it???

Comment: @ChrisStratton Who is complaining about what now?

Comment: He's not wrong, principally speaking. There are a lot of cases where the posts are being closed/changed or diminishedly replied to because people didn't understand the issue and assumed a lot of stuff. We should take note that he replied politely and to-the-point. That calls for respect. Of course there are a lot of lesser posts that cause that response but the eagerness of "correcting" here on SO has on occasion gone over to the mob mentality. (I haven't read **his** posts, though. Just making the point. He shouldn't have mailed you, though. But maybe he wants to keep it private.)

Comment: @ChrisStratton This question was far from great.

Comment: The question has been undeleted and I've put in a flag to have the close reason point at the duplicate question.

Comment: The core problem here is closing as off-topic what appears to be a perfectly *on-topic* question.  Unfortunately, this is a common problem at SO, and IMHO one of the core flaws of the "reputation" system here.  Apparently, hyperactive behavior on these forums does *not* imply the good judgment that the reputation system assumes that it does.

Comment: @RBarryYoung You're not correct. the question as of now is off-topic, since it's missing a MCVE to reproduce the problem. A description of symptoms simply isn't enough to provide more than guesses at what the problem could be. The research in the question is well executed and rules out quite some possible issues, but without code the question will remain off-topic. This is because by all means a frozen UI can't describe working code and the question asks for a way to fix it. And it's stated in the help center that such questions need the minimal code to reproduce to be on-topic.

Comment: There should be a tradeoff between the ideal clarity and the level of understanding and familiarity of a post by the people who can answer it. Sometimes posting a question here turns to be time waisting quarrel with moderators.

Comment: I don't understand...  From the edit history it looks like he edited his own question to remove the detail and add a comment and you removed the comment from his post, completely appropriate.  Not only is it a confusing and nearly impossible to answer question, but he claims a post solved it that contains the only information that could give a solution and that is missing from his question, the use of certain 3rd party controls...

Answer (score 87):

To begin, I am sorry you feel frustrated with how your question was handled. One thing to keep in mind is that those in the community who do volunteer their time to help moderate don't go out randomly editing/closing questions because we're bored. Most of us use the review system, which jams post after post after post down our throats in succession. Sometimes things blend together or slip through the cracks. I'm not trying to make any excuses for anyone, but we are all human here. We want to make people feel welcome here, not drive them away due to petty incidents.

So, to get to your post. I can tell you that my process is always to cut the fluff out of questions/answers and get them to the point. This is a technical site so we expect our questions/answers to follow that same ideology.

Your original question had quite a bit of information in it. That is great! That's how it should be. You explained exactly your issue and what your symptoms were. However, the one thing you are missing is *why* you think your problem was happening and possible code snippets for us to troubleshoot.

I can make a post saying...

> My car wouldn't start this morning. I found out that it wouldn't start
>   if I cranked it for 2 seconds or 5 seconds. One thing special I do is
>   put my foot on the brake when trying to start it.

How do I begin to troubleshoot that? It could be a starter, it could be a battery, it could be the engine, I could be out of gas. Without troubleshooting on my end, I have nothing more to share, so my question becomes extremely broad and unlikely to help others in my specific situation. Someone else's car could be out of gas while it is my starter that was the issue.

**This is likely why your original question was put on hold.** As I personally did not vote on that process, I couldn't share what the 5 people who did were thinking.

At this point, you edited all the good content out of your own question and replaced it with a personal narrative of frustration; this is what I saw while going through the review queue. Unfortunately, many casual users of the site might see that as a turn-off to wanting to help you. I generally edit out salutations, valedictions, and any other anecdotes that do not pertain to the question. **My goal is to make questions clear and precise to attract the most quality answers.** That is why I removed your comments from the question.

In the end, I'm happy that you found a similar question which helped you resolve your issue. In hindsight, your question should have been closed as a duplicate of that question. Perhaps a diamond mod could change that to point others who do experience some of your symptoms at that question.

Again, our goal here on Stack Overflow is to help others, plain and simple. Those who choose to moderate also take on the additional responsibility of trying to assist others to find the best help. Not everything is black and white when it comes to moderation and sometimes things like this happen. What I personally want you to take away from this is that it was never personal, we welcome your contributions to the community, and we hope you'll continue to participate in the future.

Comment: Yours is a very well constructed reply. Hopefully he will respond positively to it.

Comment: That's a great response.

Comment: The original question was much more specific and detailed than your car example. The equivalent car question would have included many possibly relevant observations such as the dashboard status light values, whether the headlights dim during attempts to start, and what sorts of sounds it makes during the start attempt - enough information for someone with experience of non-starting cars to distinguish between battery, out of gas, and engine. I would have voted to reopen the original question if I had been aware of it.

Comment: I've seen the [original revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27988236/1) of this question and I've actually upvoted it when it was still open. Why? Because IMO it was well-written, as detailed as possible, was about an unusual issue, and the OP took care to explain it wasn't just another stupid infinite loop. I think **if someone from the community had a similar problem in the past he could provide some insight/solution**. It's a shame it was just trashed like that instead.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Describing code and how it behaves with natural language instead of showing the actual code that can reproduce the issue is never "as detailed as possible", an is definitely not an example of a well-written question.

Comment: @BartoszKP when you can't reproduce an issue, you describe everything to the best of your abilities. That's what I meant. And you ask **whether someone had the same issue** out of despair. Because then, people who could have a clue could ask for more details. And it was surely much better written than the average SO question. By well-written I mean the post didn't contain errors, was carefully formatted, was clear, and was researched. I can't say as much about most of the questions that show up in the tags I follow.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski When you can't reproduce the issue at all you just don't post on SO, because it's not suitable for vague discussions and guessing. Asking whether someone had the same issue is also not in scope of this site (at least not *just* that). I agree the question was *better* then average in terms of syntax. But nothing more.

Comment: The user is right. If you want to help but don't know an answer ignore the question. Many questions are moderated by users who don't understand the questions they edit.

Comment: @BartoszKP It contained enough information for anyone who has encountered the same or a similar problem to recognise that it's the same problem and give you the solution. You can't stick code to every question and sometimes an MCVE is impossible to construct. The question was definitely better written and researched than 99% of all the questions I come across (including all of my questions) and given the intermittent nature of the problem a lack of MCVE was completely justified.

Comment: @biziclop No, it didn't. There are tons of possible reasons for an application to "freeze". So someone else's problem could manifest in the same way, but it could still be a different problem. And the author of the question has the code that reproduces the problem. He can and should try to cut it down to the smallest piece in which the problem still persists. So no, the lack of MCVE was not justified.

Comment: @user246408 Whether you know the answer or not is irrelevant to the quality of the question. And you shouldn't ever ignore bad questions. I understand the question in the original revision well, but it really boils down to "I have a complicated app that sometimes freezes" + some clues, that might be, or might be not relevant, and are mostly extremely localized. They prove however that the OP has the code that reproduces the issue, so he can and should (see also my comment above) prepare a MCVE.

Comment: @BartoszKP So what it boils down to is that since YOU can't figure out what the problem could be based on the data provided, clearly no-one else can. I on the other hand am used to solving problems far less specified because very specific error conditions tend to only be caused by very specific starting conditions. So it really is just a matter of what you're used to, don't assume that something is impossible just because you can't imagine it being possible.

Comment: @biziclop What you are used to is irrelevant in the context of this site's standards. Very specific error conditions are also, by definition, not general, so there is very low probability of being helpful to other people in the future. You still don't know which of these specific error conditions are relevant and which are not. I really don't understand why do you advocate describing code's behaviour over just showing the code. Yes, it takes work to strip irrelevant parts, but that's the work you must do most of the time to diagnose the problem. And you end up with *clear* problem statement.

Comment: @BartoszKP ...that is so specific (not to mention unsearchable), it really IS of no help to everyone else but the person who asked the question. Should SO be a real knowledge base or just a site where people post code and other people post what that code does? It seems to me you're an advocate of the latter while claiming to strive for the former. The trouble is, you don't need an expert to tell you what a code does, just run it on a computer and it'll do it.

Comment: @biziclop That's a radical trivialization - typical straw man argument. I'm an advocate of (mostly) what's clearly explained in the SO's help center. I have nothing against very localized problems being solved, as long as they are presented as clearly as possible. And clearly, in the discussed case, OP could do more work to prepare a code sample, that resolves many ambiguities, inherent in natural language. Even if it wasn't a MCVE, because of network communication or some other external dependencies, it would be much closer to meeting SO's policy.

Comment: @BartoszKP It's not a matter of what you think you are against. The more code-heavy the question, the more localised the problem. The more localised the problem, the less useful it is as a knowledge base. You want code in every trouble-shooting question, therefore you are working towards a less useful knowledge base. But you're right, I'm exaggerating to show you where certain attitudes lead when followed blindly. I'm not saying we shouldn't close vague questions, all I'm saying is that more consideration and leniency is needed when someone has clearly put in the effort.

Comment: @biziclop Glad that you've noticed that. So perhaps stop implying what I think I'm against or not - I agree it's irrelevant, but it's you who started this tangential subject.

 **Ad rem:** you are right that the more code-heavy the question is, the more localised the problem. However, we are discussing a completely opposite situation were there is no code at all. The the less code there is in the question, the more vague it gets. I agree that OP's diagnostic information are helpful, but the OP still could and should have provide *some* code to illustrate more precisely what are they doing.

Comment: I think I'm repeating myself for the N-th time and I've said everything I have to say in this topic, so I'll stop here. Cheers!

Comment: "I am sorry you feel frustrated with how your question was handled."  This is wrongheaded.  Your apology is not a real apology.  Please learn to do it right, or omit it altogether.  https://www.huffpost.com/entry/im-sorry-you-feel-that-way-apology_n_5acd47e5e4b06a6aac8cce67

Answer (score 25):

I'm the original poster of the question and the reason this blog post was started. Thanks for the discusson. There are some really good points in there.

Let me share my final perspective on this issue before we all move on :-)

First of all: I have built a software company with 7 developers from the ground up and I have 15 years of experience in Windows programming with several different languages. Among other things, we also develop software for critical fields such as aviation and medicine. So I think it's fair to claim that when I ask a question online, it's not because I'm too lazy to google or too stupid to try other things. Also, I do believe that I when I write something (such as my original post), I try to be as precise and scientific as possible given the circumstances and known facts.

So some of you may understand that it was frustrating and almost insulting to see my question flagged within minutes or hours. But I'll try to keep my personal feelings aside for the rest of my post:

Please bear with me for a few paragraphs, it'll all lead to a conclusion :-)

I would say that in programming there are two broad types of problems:

**PROBLEM TYPE A:**

- Can be reproduced easily
- **Can be reproduced every time it is run**
- Code for reproduction can be isolated
- **Has a clearly identifiable cause, but the cause is not the solution. This fact is important!**
- Common Examples: NullReferenceException, infinite loop, stack overflow (pun intended). Let's say you have an unexpected NullRefException in a piece of code. So you know the cause of the problem but you want to ask for a solution/workaround on stack overflow.

**PROBLEM TYPE B:**

- Can NOT be reproduced by a clear and specific sequence of actions
- Happens irregularly (NOT every time the code is run)
- Code for reproduction is almost impossible to isolate (Pausing the debugger will break somewhere in Application.Run() or in another useless method)
- Cause can not be determined at the time of posting the question. Once you know the cause, you automatically have the solution, because **THE CAUSE IS THE SOLUTION**
- Examples: Timing issues, sporadic freezing, some thread deadlocks, unstable network behavior, etc.

Looking at my original question in this light, you will come to realize that it was a clear Type B question and therefore it was downright pointless to request a clearly reroducible piece of code from me. That would have taken days or weeks (given that we also use tons of third party components), and it would have solved the problem automatically (as indicated above).

I think we all can agree to the fact that any type of forum is pointless if the asker has to spend days or weeks on investigations just so he gets allowed to actually ask his/her question. If those are really the terms, then we don't need an online exchange between professionals, and everyone can go about their separate ways.

So is it is my understanding that when ever a question of type B is asked on stack overflow, it is flagged because no reproduction code was submitted. This also happened to my question. But is this fair? Are questions of type B really inferior? I would say they're just different in nature, but some people fail to embrace this fact. They want to make everything clearly reproducible when in fact that's just impossible or not justifiable. In fact, any programmer who claims he's never had a type B problem in his career is downright lying. It would be nice if we only had type A's, but it's not realistic.

My issue turned out to be so special that it didn't even occur when a debugger was attached. It only occurred in production. There was no exception and hence no stack trace, nothing. The UI just froze. So anyone who knows better, let me know how I should have submitted an exception, call stack or reproduction code for such a problem: The problem disappeared the second the debugger was attached.

Since I was not granted help on stackoverflow, I continued my intensive research and compared symptoms with older stackoverflow posts. Ironically, that's how I found the solution: On another, older  SO thread that was considered OK back then. When I mentioned my finding, someone commented that this older post must have slipped through the crack and also should have been flagged in the first place. This comment really got me thinking:

**Have we really come this far that the way a question is asked is considered more important than the fact that it keeps helping other people on a daily basis? Is this really what you guys want SO to be or become?**

In the end my problem turned out to be a bug that is known to be almost impossible to diagnose. It was caused by a third party component which I identified and reported to the vendor. I even helped the vendor solve this problem and they were very grateful.

THAT's how problem solving is done right! Together, not against one another. It is not up to me to judge anyone's question, but to check whether I can provide a viable answer. If I can't or don't fully understand the question, then chances are high someone else will!

Best regards to all of you,
Marco

Comment: _"Have we really come this far that the way a question is asked is considered more important than the fact that it keeps helping other people on a daily basis? Is this really what you guys want SO to be or become?"_ - for me, for one, yes. There's always a new way to ask the same question (not saying your question has been asked before), while SO wanted and still tries to be a **knowledge base**. Knowledgeable people are a scarce resource; only so many questions can get answered daily. If you want a discussion, a list of opinions, hand-held debugging, try a forum.

Comment: I feel like sometimes moderators are (i'm including myself) sceptic about the quality of a question when it comes from a low-rep user. It makes sense, as generaly low quality questions are formulated by low-rep users, one can hope that a 4k user knows already how to write a good question in SO. That have been said, I believe that due to your good knowledge and SO-friendly opinions and views, you should be awarded with 2K rep! However, be friendly with the mods also! They are volunteers that sometimes may make mistakes. Good job and hope to see you around more in SO!

Comment: It is unlikely to be misjudged by many. Probably *something* was wrong in question. Everybody here had their day of *first downvoted hard question*. The question is what will you do: will you write an angry email to moderator or will you try to *improve* the question? When I answer people questions I will rely on their *score* to get basic understanding of how good are they at *using* of SO. If score is low and question is poor - it will likely to get downvotes. Because they have to learn. And life is a pain. If nobody will *teach*,then SO become garbage (requiring more and more moderation).

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't know how far can you continue? most common and general questions have been asked, and there are many duplicates of them. Isn't now a time to let some more specific questions raise and the OP benefit from the knowledge of the experts here?

Comment: @Sinatr Your reply sums up perfectly a lot of what's wrong with SO. Reputation is no reliable indicator of quality. It is an indicator of activity. And closing perfectly valid questions as off topic isn't going to make anyone learn anything other than to steer clear of this snobby and elitist place which seems to welcome only the easy questions that generate a lot of reps to the people who answer them. (I'm not saying that's all what SO is about, but that's the impression that forms in a new user who gets his or her good question closed as off-topic by a bunch of random passers-by.)

Comment: On this: " So I think it's fair to claim that when I ask a question online, it's not because I'm too lazy to google or too stupid to try other things" - your personality and history of striving is not visible on a Stack Overflow question. Just the question text. It is important to treat the question objectively, and not treat criticism of it as personal insults. SO attracts a lot of engineers with fault-finding mentality. That means they will find faults . . . I am sure you are aware of this if you ever run any meetings with engineers inside your own company.

Comment: I understand the frustration, but "type B" questions, as you call them, are really hard for anybody to answer. If it'll take "days or weeks" for you to find the answer, it seems pretty unlikely that anybody is going to be able to solve it for you on Stack Overflow in a few minutes or hours, especially since they have much *less* information than you do.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that the rules and moderation techniques of Stack Overflow have evolved over the years as well. Rules and guidelines we followed back in 2011 (when the second question he referred to was written) were likely much different than today. So that question didn't necessarily "slip through the cracks," it was just a different time.

Comment: @MattBurland Does that mean hard questions are unwelcome then? Should we limit questions to what can be answered off the cuff? I know that isn't what you're saying and I can accept your argument in this case but I fear it's the thin end of the wedge.

Comment: @biziclop: No, it means they don't fit the Q&A format as well. They require in-depth discussion with somebody who is intimately familiar with the code (which random people on the internet aren't likely to be). You can ask those questions, by all means. You might get lucky. Or sometimes it isn't clear if you have a type A or type B question. But don't be surprised if you don't get the response you want.

Comment: @MattBurland I agree, it's not a best fit for the Q&A format. It isn't a particularly good fit for the often cited "forum" solution. And it's potentially valuable knowledge. And if you don't get a response, that's fine, it happens. And if, after some time elapsed, there still is no activity, the question should be closed and deleted. Not even being given the chance to get a response based on vague and subjective assumptions about what can and can't be solved is what I don't agree with. (The post was closed within 18 minutes of posting, hardly enough time to judge a question's merits.)

Comment: This isn't about the question's importance. SO's formula simply is less "type B question friendly". It doesn't make these questions any less a reality in this job, it's just that it would be nearly impossible to construct a pertinent and usable knowledge base of problems / solutions for those. You'd end up browsing through thousands of "why my app doesn't work" questions, each with different answers - or no answers at all. That would make SO far less efficient for the community.

Comment: At best you can try to isolate the code segment you suspect the most as being the cause of the problem, show it and ask why it could randomly fail / cause problems. The answer may not solve *all* of your problem but it could still lead you - or someone else - in the right direction.

Comment: @biziclop: I'm not disagreeing that the trigger on close votes is pulled too quickly in many cases, but note that it's not a "close", it's a "hold". Although I don't know how many question successful manage to reverse a "hold" or whether users really bother to try and get their question reopened.

Comment: Also, on this: *It was caused by a third party component which I identified and reported to the vendor.* Tell me, from your own experience on this field, how anyone could have this figured out only by reading your question? *Even* if you were lucky enough to have someone making the right guess (after all people *do* sometimes win playing roulette), that would still only be just that: a guess. Could *you* benefit from a KB that's full of wild, random presumptions? To get the best of SO you must try to isolate the problem as much as you can first. **You must help people into helping you**.

Comment: @Crono: The third party lib was just the component that caused the issue. It could also have been caused by my own code, that's not the point. The point is: Anyone who had experienced this issue prior to me could have helped me solve/identify it. Here's a comparison: Even if doctor A doesn't have all the lab results to show to doctor B, the two of them can still try to pin down a suspected disease via dialog and by ruling out symptoms. And this is the part that didn't take place in my post. Basically doctors C,D and E decided they wanted the (non-existant) lab results first.

Comment: @Marco I understand what you mean but that's just not how StackOverflow works. It isn't meant to provide you with additional eyes on your complete, unique software. It's to get help on solving actual coding issues, as in "what's missing in this code segment so that it does this or that", or "why when using this function I get result x and not the documented result y". No one is claiming your question in itself is wrong and can't ever be asked (or answered to) anywhere else on the net. The point is that it's not the kind of question SO was designed for and that's why it gets rejected.

Comment: @Crono: As stated before, my question ha a single specific cause.It was not a question for a second pair of eyes as you put it. But let's ask SO ourselves, shall we? Quoted from "how-to-ask": _"Introduce the problem before you post any code"_ Yep, I did that. _"Not all questions benefit from including code"_: Yep, that's exactly what I was saying, and SO says so too. _"Include all relevant tags"_ Yep, did that. _"Proof-read before posting"_ Yep, did that. -> IOW: All broad guidelines were followed. So who really did violate the SO terms? The one who asked, or the ones who flagged my question?

Comment: @Marco If by "my question has a single specific cause" you mean "in the end it was a simple problem that caused the behavior" (sorry, my english isn't that good), then I'm afraid you're still missing the point: the question *could* have many valid answers. Now knowing the cause you can say it didn't but back then it was impossible to tell: people could at best make a guess about what was wrong. It could have been your code, your computer, a parallel task getting in the way... all of these could also have explained an app freeze. Again, THIS is why your question was likely put on hold.

Comment: Also from SO's help center: *if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format (...) There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Comment: One more thing: on *"Introduce the problem before you post any code"* and *"not all questions benefit from including code"*, I personally read *"first describe your problem, THEN post some code"* and *"MOST questions benefit from including code"*. Of course this is my very own personal interpretation, but if you end up spending enough time here you'll see that the questions that gets the most attention do indeed follow these rules.

Comment: @Marco No matter how much you are frustrated, they first feel sympathy for you, then justify their actions :), if it happens more this blessing is not  repeated and they may punish you. sorry for bad English

Comment: `blog post`; Meta *is not* a blog, and does not try to be one.

Comment: Are you [Talmon Marco](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmon_Marco)?

Answer (score 12):

I don't think it happens too often, it only seems to happen if you post your email into your profile (for purposes such as offering additional help) or a user *really* wants to contact you so urgently they venture out to find your email address on the internet.

By chance I was in a similar situation last week and the conversation kept pleasant, but it's [pretty well-documented on Meta that these emails do turn violent sometimes.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277134/abusive-aggressive-users-taking-it-outside-of-stack-overflow/277137#277137)

I'll put the conversation here for reference on how you could go around replying to the user that contacted you.

*Their first email:*

> I am new to stackoverflow and just started recently posting.  I am not
>   100% sure on how it works and I am sorry.  I just wanted them to have
>   the right answer and I don't care really about credit although it is
>   nice to get once in a while.  I know you have been posting for years
>   but I am new to this so please give me a break.

*My response*:

---

> Hi there,
>
> That’s fine, everyone has to start somewhere. I admit that I had a bad
>   start on Stack Overflow when I registered a couple of years ago too. I
>   think it’s brilliant that you want to share your knowledge with
>   others;  Stack Overflow has many users who simply register on Stack
>   Overflow, ask a question  and never return the favour of even marking
>   the solution to their question as 'accepted'.
>
> A few tips for answering questions:
>
> - Never answer a question unless you’re sure it answers the question
> - Ensure to read any edits or comments anyone makes to the question or existing answers- you wouldn't want to waste time writing an answer to
>     a question only to find the OP (original poster) already tried that
> - Provide complete solutions, a half-complete solution is of no use to anyone
> - Never provide an answer being of ‘Go to example.com and you’ll find it there’. links rot and become outdated very quickly. so basically
>     you’ll want to link to the resource but however provide the content
>     that matters to the question (such as a function) from the link
> - Link to official documentation where possible
>
> If have any questions regarding answering questions, just ask, I don't
>   bite.

---

We emailed each-other back and forth for a few days; the user was asking how to improve.

***The trick here is to be polite, even if the user is being rude.***

Comment: Reason for the disagreement (-1)?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I had to zoom in to read the image.

Comment: Didn't like having to zoom either. Converted image to text.

Comment: @Matt Point taken.

Comment: I don't see how it's related to the OP. It's more about "why this question has been edited", than "how to handle users emails".

Comment: @cosmo0 No, the *question* actually asks 'how do I handle this'?

Comment: Well I don't see it that way, but I can be wrong. However, if it's the case, it's a question about "how to deal with angry people", and probably off-topic for SO (even meta). I mean, good luck with that.

Comment: @cosmo0 This bit in the question suggests so: `it could be beneficial to others in the future. It also allows the community to have a discussion about the issue or chime in on any points I might have missed.`. It's an informational/discussion post rather than an actual question.