# Best practices for argumentative comments

Tags: discussion

I would like suggestions for best practices for people that want to 'debate' or put 'argumentative' comments to answers posted.

It happened to me earlier today, to the point that I just deleted my answer, rather than have the argumentative comments.

Comment: If the comments are unconstructive or rude, flag them appropriately, if someone is trying to constructively discuss the topic, then either participate or don't, those are your options.

Comment: It would be great if there was an example. Some users who receive suggestions from the community will be defensive and create an argument that's not so much about the post's content.

Comment: Respond with your counter argument?  Then let it go if you can't come to some accord, and there is nothing left to argue?  Listen, you, if you keep deleting your questions because somebody gets a little caustic in their friggen comments you're going to get the autoban.  So buck up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The best advice I can give you is to DISENGAGE:**

> 1. **Ignore them; stop responding or otherwise engaging.**
> 2. Use whatever abuse management tools are available to you elsewhere (e.g. blocking / reporting users on twitter, email inbox filters,
>      etc).
> 3. Keep on truckin'.

Source: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277135/950427

**I have been through this before and Meta SO has led me here:** https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76172/233438 and here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66445/233438.

> - Post to Meta Stack Exchange (this site)
>
>   - This is probably what you were thinking of doing, since you ended up here in the first place. If you're not clear on whether a user is
>       really doing something wrong, you can ask about it here on Meta. But
>       if you're not comfortable with mentioning names in public, there are
>       other options.
> - Post to the per-site Meta
>
>   - If the problem is happening on a site other than Meta Stack Exchange, you can post to the site's own Meta.
> - Send e-mail to the admins
>
>   - You can always e-mail via the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) form with your concerns.
>       That link is in the footer bar of every single Stack Exchange web
>       page.
> - Flag for a moderator
>
>   - You can send short messages directly to moderators by clicking the "flag" link under posts or the little flag icon next to comments and
>       choosing "Flag for moderator attention."
> - Flag, but **not** for a moderator
>
>   - If it's truly blatant spam or hate speech, you should be able to just flag as such directly. Enough such flags and the system will take
>       care of the problem automatically, no need for any time-consuming
>       human effort! Beyond the 1.5 seconds it takes to do the actual
>       flagging, anyways.

If the bad behavior happens again, please refer to the [contact us page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76172/233438).

### If you believe that your answer is worth adding to SO, DO NOT feel discouraged and delete it. The SO mods will deal with the situation.