# How to show appreciation to a user on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, comments

I'm pleased for the help I've received from some user on the site. So I want to make some notes to describe the helpful users.

How can I do this? Is it possible?

Usually we accept answers, or up vote user posts.

Are there any other methods to show appreciation?

Comment: **To show appriciation:** Accept the answer, or upvote. **To describe him:** Um, on chat?

Comment: if i want tell some more??

Comment: Where ever you want, as long as it's not on SE. Use your blog, website, social networks, whatever. But it's not appropriate for any site on the SE network.

Comment: @Abdulla , if you must thank them in some other way than upvoting and accepting answers, then giving them a Bounty or having a chat would be the only things left that you can do on SE.

Answer (score 18):

**To show appreciation to a user:**

- Upvote their *useful* answer/question - this will show that you appreciate them posting a high-quality question as per [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- Accept the answer - if you asked a question and someone gave a solution that helped you, you can always accept the answer (this will show appreciation without any need of "Thank you" comments)
- For really outstanding help, spend some of your points on a bounty, which attracts more attention and is a nice reward by itself

**To talk to the user:**

- Ask them to join you in [the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)
- Try and see if they'll talk to you on another platform (ie: Skype or a forum). Stack Exchange is a Q&A site purely for high-quality questions and answers *without* the noise of discussion - so try and not discuss general things on here.

**To clarify:**

- Serial voting, which is defined as voting on a user instead of on specific posts you organically come to as they deserve is frowned upon, regardless of intent. Please read [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/246338)

Comment: Given OPs confusion, you should probably make it clear that one should _not_ go on an upvote spree as serial voting is frowned upon.

Comment: @hd Seems good?? Thats its?? No any other methods??

Comment: @l4mpi good point, thanks!

Comment: @Abdulla I'm really unsure what your goal is. StackExchange is a q&a site not a discussion board. Perhaps a forum (with Q&A functionality) would be better suited for you?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ , a Bounty would also be good.

Comment: @Abdulla: well then why not use what you learned and accept this answer.

Comment: @Abdulla: as per Jongware's suggestion, would you accept this answer? To do so, click on the tick mark to the left hand side, so that it turns green. This is how we thank people for their time and assistance on the SE sites.

Answer (score -3):

[Phone them and tell them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261178/what-do-you-do-when-someone-calls-you-personally-about-an-answer?rq=1)

Comment: That's amazing hahaha