# Add a thanks button to the answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In Quora when somebody answers a question and you find it useful you can thank the user who asked the question. I think this is a great feature, with the main advantage of not scaring away people who take the time to answer, but because they not being very experienced yet in a subject, his answers are not the best. It's basically promoting the Q&A system beginning from an 'early age'. It is also probably easy to implement.

Contrary to an upvote, which means that the answer is a good one, I may want to thank somebody for taking the time to write a long answer, despite it being wrong.

It would also remove the Thanks! noise in the comments.

For example, in Quora, you can Upvote *and* Thanks. They are different buttons.

What do you think?

Remember that the comments section is not the place to say thanks.

There would not be any kind of Thanks counter. The only practical difference is that the person who answered will get a popup saying "XXX thanked you for XXX answer".

Comment: There's an upvote button that does the same thing.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan An upvote means that the answer is a good one. I may want to thank somebody for taking the time to write a long answer, despite being wrong.

Comment: What would be the point @NicSzer?

Comment: Quora != StackOverflow. We don't need the extra noise on these here. The advantages may be obvious to you, but you will need to list them for the community :/

Comment: *Answer: 2 upvotes, 1337 Thanks*

Comment: Thank you for the question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov flagged as too chatty ...

Comment: "*Contrary to an upvote, which means that the answer is a good one, I may want to thank somebody for taking the time to write a long answer, despite it being wrong.*" ... why should I or the person writing the answer, care? If it's wrong, then it needs to be *corrected*. So it should be downvoted, perhaps with an explanation of what is wrong. Your thanks is irrelevant and not helpful towards the end of creating good information.

Comment: "with the advantages being obvious" - there is absolutely no indication why this is advantageous or even remotely useful for Q&A site (may have some value for forum or other type of site). Please [edit] post to add explanation.

Comment: @NicSzer if you feel the need to thank them, leave a comment.  If it isn't worth the time to do that, then it obviously didn't matter enough to you.  Bonus to leaving a comment-  you can say "thank you but it didn't work because..." and help explain to future readers why it didn't work.

Comment: When @GabeSechan says post a comment, he actually means don't post anything at all.  It's not useful to anyone.

Comment: @GabeSechan And I'm saying that you shouldn't be posting such comments, and they even merit flagging.  That's not what comments are for.  Comments exist to provide useful information that can help improve a post, not to socialize with people.  There are lots of places where it *is* appropriate to socialize with people, but SO comments isn't one of them.

Comment: This would actually remove noise from the comments section.

Comment: @Servy And I'm saying I don't care what you think.  Comments are for discussions between the people reading the question.   Thanking someone is a basic social interaction that both makes someone's effort feel appreciated and increases the likelihood that they'll continue on the site.  Removing such things is harmful, idiotic, and bad for the site.  Anyone who does so makes the site worse.  Noone should be forced to make such comments, but anyone who wishes to should.

Comment: @GabeSechan: "*Removing such things is harmful, idiotic, and bad for the site.*" And yet, it is site policy. So however much you may disagree with it, every moderator will respond to flagging such comments with instant removal.

Comment: @GabeSechan It's not just what I think; it's what the site's rules are.  Comments are a tool to allow people to provide information to improve a post, for which saying "thanks" doesn't accomplish that.  Thanking someone is a social interaction that is appropriate in some situations and not others.  Having comments sections flooded with "thanks" comments is harmful, idiotic, and bad for the site.  Anyone who does so makes the site worse.

Comment: @NicolBolas And its bad policy, so I'll continue to fight it.  In fact, in your honor I'm thanking the next 10 good posts I read.

Comment: @Servy Bad rules should be broken

Comment: @GabeSechan You mean like your "rule" that you should always thank everyone for everything, even when doing so is harmful?

Comment: @Servy when did I say you should thank everyone?  You shouldn't.  But you should do so when you wish to, for example a good answer that doesn't quite solve the question would be a candidate.

Comment: @GabeSechan If it doesn't answer the question then it's not a good answer.  By definition, in fact.

Comment: @Servy Not at all.  If it gets you part of the way there, then its a good answer.  Most of the best answers I've had here haven't answered my question, but they showed me the right path.

Comment: @GabeSechan If it's part way there then it's part way to a good answer.  When it gets there, then it can become a good answer.  By your definition all answers are "part way" to a good answer, and are therefore all good answers.

Comment: @Servy if you really think that, you must ask nothing but very trivial questions.

Comment: @GabeSechan I've only ever asked two questions here (I'm assuming we're not talking about meta, because meta is weird), one that I didn't know the answer to when I posted.  You can read that one question and consider whether or not you think it's trivial.

Comment: What's the difference between an upvote of an answer which the title text says *"**This answer is useful**"* to the thought of *"**thanks, this answer is useful to me**"*. also you should never be thanking an answerer for posting an incorrect answer regardless of it's length.

Comment: @Memor-X In a thought experiment, it is easy to imagine someone clicking this button instead of writing "Thanks". It would reduce "Thanks" comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show appreciation to a user on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: Now it's a feature: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/17/saying-thanks-testing-a-new-reactions-feature/

Answer (score 29):

There is already a button that we use "to thank somebody for taking the time to write a long answer, despite it being wrong". It is called a downvote.

A downvote lets the poster know that you took the time to look at their post and that you might have even read the entire thing and thought about it. If you *don't* vote on their post, they might have no idea anyone even *saw* it.

Comment: In case part of this isn't ironic, the downvote by no means thanks.

Comment: @NicSzer it at least lets the poster know that you saw their post. If you don't vote at all, the poster doesn't necessarily know that *anyone* saw their answer.

Comment: lol "Thanks for answering! *-1*"

Answer (score 18):

I could potentially see some merit in adding a "thanks" button that does literally nothing, just to honeypot people into not posting comments that aren't useful or upvoting bad content "as thanks".  I don't really think such a feature is going to do enough good to actually be worth the time it would take to implement, or all the effort it would expend explaining to all of the people asking what it does that it's a honeypot.

Comment: I don't understand why my net votes go down and this answer's net votes go up, despite it mentioning a good thing about the question's proposal.

Why is it?

Comment: @NicSzer Well, the answer *does* say it wouldn't be worth the effort, and the answer also includes the notable difference of having it not actually do anything, thus actively subverting the purpose of the proposal.

Comment: True, thanks! Didn't consider it before.

Comment: I wonder if it is worth a trial? It may significantly reduce the number of "thanks" posts (including "thanks answers"). It is, sort of, the effect of "upvoting" when you are not logged in (although I think that does something, or used to). Button you can click. Much easier than typing, people will go for it. However, perhaps Meta would fill up with "Where's the count of my Thanks!" and "I thanked someone 17 times, and the system didn't stop me"? And "What's the daily Thanks limit?"? Button could even say "this actually does nothing, but allows you to feel that you have thanked the person".

Comment: @BillWoodger If the button tells you it does nothing then it fails as a honeypot, as people will then go on to do exactly the things we want them to not do.

Comment: Well, I'm just suggesting honesty :-) I'm sure if it were done as a true Honeypot (metaphorically) there'd be... complaints, here and elsewhere. The idea of the foam hammer is to use it. It is known to be foam, and known to have an intended purpose. Thus the Thanks button which "allows you to feel that you have thanked the person". Placebo rather than Honeypot.

Comment: @BillWoodger That's just it; a placebo isn't particularly effective as a placebo if you *know* that it's a placebo (it can sometimes have *some* effect, but nowhere near the "standard" placebo effect).