# How do I ask if a question was resolved?

Tags: discussion

What is the best way to ask someone if they ever found an answer to their question? For example, I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27282319/5037020) question, and it was asked seven months ago. What is the best way to ask if the issue has been resolved (so that I could use the same solution)? Should I comment on the question? Or is there another standard approach?

Comment: [Who were you DenverCoder9? What did you see?](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: [Good evening, sorry to bother you. Is it you who asked a JavaScript question on StackOverflow some time ago?](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/03/03/stackoverflow-youre-not-alone/)

Comment: @Ajedi32 [What do you do when someone calls you personally about an answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261178/what-do-you-do-when-someone-calls-you-personally-about-an-answer)

Comment: were you able to get a resolution to this question? I wanted to find out but wasn't sure how to proceed.

Comment: Simple comment on it buddy and hope OP is still active. Or you can post your question , it will not be considered duplicate as original don't have any answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If it's the same exact question as you have,

1. Once you have the appropriate rep, [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask if the OP found a solution and hope he answers back.
2. Vote the question up
3. When you have enough reputation, you could [offer a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on the question to get it more attention.
4. edit the question if there is anything you can do to make the question better **without** changing the meaning of the question or the askers intent.

Comment: Apart from what you mentioned :- Don't add new answer and ask OP "is problem solved"?

Comment: Personally, I think "Does anyone know if such a thing exists?" makes the question sound like a tool request. I kind of want to change it to "Is this possible?" but then it might be too broad. "Is there an existing option for this in Visual Studio or Visio?" might be too different from the author's intent.

Comment: A fairly important note: if you vote the question up, the owner will receive some reputation and they will get a notification of this the next time they visit the site, thus reminding them of the existence of the question.

Answer (score 6):

If a question does not have any answers, other questions cannot be duped against it.  This is an intentional limitation.  If you have a question which is not adequately answered elsewhere on the site, you can ask it anew, even if it is unanswered elsewhere.

Now, just because you *can* do this doesn't mean you should.  If the other question is well-worded, a bounty is probably a more effective means of getting an answer.  But for old, unloved questions that never got answers, you may have better luck asking a brand-new question.