# User sent me an email after downvoting and leaving a closing vote of another user's question

Tags: support

The comment that made me question:

> @gsamaras I sent you an e-mail. – theUser 1 min ago

That user seems to have a high reputation. However, I am *afraid* that I might see content that will be not OK and when something is not OK I tend to remember and get sad for some time.

I mean why not just tell me in the comment what he wants (after all he is commenting). What would you do? Has this ever happened to you?

Comment: Related [What do you do when someone calls you personally about an answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261178)

Comment: @BhargavRao interested story, thanks, but the phone call is different from an e-mail.

Comment: Yep. When I said *related*, I meant *Also see*... :)

Comment: and what was the email?

Comment: If you're not willing to read emails originating from SO users, I'm having trouble understanding why you would make your email address discoverable from SO at all. Is there some prior bad history with this user that's making you feel this way?

Comment: Well, I'd read the email first.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Read the email or not, then move on.

Comment: Before opening the email take 5 steps away from the monitor, turn your head away slightly, squint your eyes and look at the monitor thorugh the cracks of your fingers, as your hand covers your face. This is how I deal when browsing things related to crustaceans or--especially--giant isopods.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> However, I am afraid that I might seem content that will be not OK

If a fellow SO user harasses you through E-Mail, do not hesitate to tell moderators about it (flag the relevant question and choose "requires moderator attention") and/or forward the E-Mail to the Stack Overflow team (`team@stackoverflow.com`).

Other than that, you'll have to live with the fact that this *can* happen. If you make an E-Mail address public, people can reach you through it and some of them can be a-holes writing nasty things. During a long SO "career" (or activity on the Internet in general) it's very likely this will happen at least once. Growing some degree of a thick skin is advisable.

If you want to make *totally* sure this doesn't happen you will have to remove all hints from your profile that let others find out your E-Mail address, but that really should be a last resort IMO.

Comment: I will become an Internet Snorlax (http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140924022259/pokemon/images/9/9f/143Snorlax_OS_anime.png) Canary Island Chief, thanks!

Comment: @gsamaras I opened the link in a new tab but then I was afraid to switch to that tab because I might see some content I do not want to see.

Comment: You know to which domain the tab belongs too @JanDvorak, IMHO it's not the same.

Comment: @gsamaras It _kinda_ isn't. But that assumes I know what wikia is and that people can't upload random content to it. The latter is not true

Comment: Why should it be the last resort to not disclose your email address? It could even be a generally recommended guideline.

Comment: @Trilarion most people who keep a public profile, are willing to be contacted, and want their SO achievements connected with themselves as a person, have a discoverable E-Mail *somewhere*. Even Jon Skeet does. It's not usually a source for problems - except, of course, in the cases where it is. would not *generally* recommend hiding it, though.

Comment: @Pekka I try to hide my email usually. But I agree, once you decide to share your email you do it with everyone and have to live with it.

Answer (score 9):

> I mean why not just tell me in the comment what he wants

It seems a little odd to write an e-mail however you could just write him that you will not read mail from total strangers. I would also mention that anything SO related should be discussed via SO (e.g. comments).

If you feel uncomfortable reading the mail then don't. There is no rule that forces you to read mail be people you don't know.

Answer (score 7):

> I mean why not just tell me in the comment what he wants (after all he is commenting).

Maybe the email is better medium for what he/she has to say?

> What would you do?

I would either answer the email or I would just ignore it.

> Has this ever happened to you?

Not from SO, no.

> However, I am afraid that I might seem content that will be not OK and when something is not OK I tend to remember and get sad for some time.

You basically put your email address for people to use and then you refuse to look at an email sent to you because it might contain something you might not like? How silly is this?

Does/did the email contain any actual abuse? If not, I am baffled this meta question even exists.

**UPDATE**

Hell, even if there ended up being abuse in the email that somebody has sent you by finding out your email address through SO, it would still not be SO's business in any way, shape or form. It is either for authorities, if it is serious, or for you to deal with. SO should not meddle in inter-personal business of two people unless the abuse was directly through SO's infrastructure like questions, answers or comments. SO should not try to evaluate "evidence" from outside its infrastructure.

Comment: I'm baffled too by the number of upvotes on this meta "question".

Answer (score 4):

You asked, "What would you do?".  Maybe this issue can make us think about "What should we do?"

As far as what you should do here on SO, simply be respectful, avoid escalating any personal interactions and let the "authorities" deal with any issue that breaks the rules.

It may be difficult to exercise restraint when an interaction feels insulting or hurtful.  I guess we would all just be unfeeling machines if we had no capacity to feel the negative emotions.  Dealing with that is a personal issue for each individual.

We could have a very long discussion about personal behavior, self-discipline, morals, right and wrong, and how we can elevate our behavior.  But, I'm not sure if getting into that is what Meta is intended for.  Basically, what you should do is simply use any notification tools, and "walk away".

For issues of how to deal with conflict resolution, maybe search elsewhere.