# User inviting others to Skype to solve their problems

Tags: discussion, behavior

Recently I have seen a user that is quite zealous in contributing to Stack Overflow.

The user is relatively new to SO (the account is only a few months old), but they have over 100 answers and about 40 questions. Their posts are not very high quality (only about 20% are upvoted with low scores), but they are also not necessarily bad either (about 75% have a score of 0, and very few have a score less than 0).

Recently I have noticed that this user has taken to leaving comments or inviting an OP to chat, letting the OP know that they can join them on [Skype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype) to work together to come to a solution. The invites to chat tend to just be a link to Skype, as opposed to actually using the chat system.

While I believe the user has mostly good intentions, it seems like a bit of a slippery slope. By using Skype, they are circumventing all voting, so the person on the receiving end may not have any idea what kind of quality they are receiving from this user. In addition, (while it doesn't *seem* to be the case with this particular user), I think it opens the door to self-promotion and spam, possibly giving a user malicious code when they think they are being helped, and other, more personal attacks.

Again, I think the user mentioned here has mostly good intentions and appears to enjoy helping others on SO. However, I worry that another user, with more harmful intent, may try to do the same thing at the OP's expense. Does SO have any kind of policy in place regarding this? If not, should there be?

Example of comment on question:

[image]

Example of the chat from that comment:

[image]

Comment: Are they clearly skype links, or are they trying to masquerade these links as SO chat links.

Comment: @KevinB edited to show 1 example.

Comment: that one example kinda makes blurring out the name not worth the effort, :p IMO it's not that big of a problem. but i have no idea whether or not it goes against any existing terms.

Comment: Hopefully they will forgive me :) I do want to focus on the user's behavior as opposed to the user themselves. I believe the user probably has good intentions when trying to work with others.

Comment: I think that's fine. If they want to help the asker, why not? If the asker is unsure about the quality of such service, then they'd have to deal with it themselves, I guess. I mean, even on SO some _bad_ answers can get many upvotes. Otherwise, if the one who invites people to Skype has malicious intentions, then... you never know whether that's true or not, so I don't think this should be banned right away.

Comment: The problem is that the users, having solved the problem off site, will probably never provide an answer on-site. So, no, it's not acceptable as future readers won't see an answer ...

Comment: assuming they never bring the answer back to SO, yes. but the same can occur with SO chat.

Comment: The user has 1337 rep so clearly they know what they're doing ;)

Comment: Reminds me of when someone was called out of the blue to help after answering a question: [What do you do when someone calls you personally about an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261178/691711)

Comment: @JeremyBanks You misunderstand my point, which is discouraging the use of Skype to solve issues. If it is solved in chat at least there is a record.

Comment: I've had a few users who have asked me to help them with their questions over Skype recently. I flat-out refuse for the reasons @DavidPostill post above, but also because that puts me at risk of falling victim to a [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) who would see my Skype address as a 24-hour helpline.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Flag the user's posts or chat message and explain all of this in a custom moderator flag.  They'll take the appropriate steps to get in touch with this person and convince them that what they're doing is not The Right Thing™ to do around here.

Otherwise, the folks here on Meta are pretty useless...we can't get in touch with that OP the same way a diamond could.

Comment: The other thing to mention is that as soon as you take something off-site by disclosing your details - there's nothing a diamond or staff can do about it anyway. So as well as loss of information that could come from a discussion and then an answer.... If it turns out the other person is either phishing or a complete nutcase etc...

Comment: Meh. Failing a moderator intervening I guess they'll stop doing that when they hit a help vampire that starts harrassing them with "plz halp" emails...

Comment: flag as soon as you get harrasment by fax.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  No, that's your own fault.  You owned a fax machine *and* gave the number out to a complete stranger online.  No amount of flagging is going to redeem you.

Comment: @Makoto Hey! Owning a fax machine is not a crime! (Perhaps having it plugged in to the phone line without an intervening spam filter is, though.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4:  I disagree; owning a functional fax machine in 2018 for non-legacy corporate workflows which you are *fighting* to get moved over to something more modern is punishable by 30 days of listening to the dial-up tone that they make, 24 hours a day; being forced to retrofit a Pentium II in your machine to run all your personal and critical apps for six months; or both.

Comment: @Makoto Some would disagree, such as the folks at [retrocomputing.se]. Fax isn't too terrible; it's easier to receive than an attached image and you can pin it to a physical noticeboard.

Comment: I lost it at fax machine.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier It was meant as an example of outdated technology (Skype was fashionable maybe ten years ago).

Comment: The real issue with fax machines is that you shell out money to print the spam you won't read. Virtual faxes are better, but you can still end up wondering where all your HDD space went.

Comment: Here's everyone talking about fax machines but nobody has mentioned the Telex :(

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in [fax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax)

Comment: Since when did Stack Overflow start punishing users wanting to help?

Comment: @SimonForsberg:  How are you really helping if the information you're sharing is buried in something completely inaccessible?  Wasn't the point of Stack Overflow to move *away* from those sorts of echo chambers and backwater forums and allow that information to flourish?

Comment: @Makoto If you are in a one-on-one chat like Skype, you can help *one* person a lot. It's sometimes not easy to write such things down in a way that can allow it to flourish. Now, if we could record the conversation of the two people involved and put it up to be shared, then it's possible others could learn from it as well.

Answer (score 28):

The person doing this likely has good intentions. The problem we have with the activity is just that this kind of help doesn't really fit how the site works.

Stack Overflow is meant to be a library of great programming answers for future readers to enjoy, not just the person we're helping out at the moment. By taking the interaction away from the site, nothing is left for those future readers.

Also, offering unpaid one-on-one help can be very... unrewarding. To the point that one can lose the motivation to help altogether. There's an endless sea of people with programming problems and we can't fix them all; and sometimes people just need to learn how to fix them themselves.

The Stack Overflow model of sharing knowledge - where you write something knowing that ideally it'll be read by many many people in the future, that you're contributing in a small way to a vast library with *some* value - is potentially much more rewarding.

That said, there is no hard rule on Stack Overflow banning what the user is doing. We don't encourage offering off-site help, we don't think it's a great idea, and if they offer their help very often and aggressively it may cause suspicion, because it could be some kind of scam.

But there is no rule against, say, putting your E-Mail or Skype contact info in your user profile and offering your help there, and from time to time telling a user in need of a helping hand that they can contact you offsite.

Answer (score 16):

Everyone, I am the user who invites everyone on Skype. I surrender.

If you guys want, I can post my screenshots of chats where I only connect to their PC using [TeamViewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeamViewer) and solve their issue, before they leave. I just explain them in one or two lines on how to ask a good questions on Stack Overflow... If helping someone in this way is not allowed... I am sorry... my intentions were to help beginners... I was a beginner once... Most of you with big reps went to places like university or college to learn, but I didn’t (couldn’t), so I know how it is to learn things by stumbling. So I try to help newcomers... I am sorry...

You guys think I am a scammer? You think I take money or have evil intentions? :( ... The first answer posted hurt me really bad... The answerer suggested to flag my account... Why? Just because I wanted to help the beginners?

Now, firstly, let me clarify a few things which are clearly mentioned in the OP's post as well:

1. I only invite beginners and I invite them from questions which are off=topic/got too many downvotes in minutes/voted to be closed down...

   If you go through my account, you’ll notice that I've gained good reps in such a short time...I know it 1.3K is not much reputation points, but for an illiterate self-taught programmer like me, it is a big achievement...

I cannot risk answering off-topic questions on this site... So I ask the OPs to join on Skype...There, I connect to their machine using TeamViewer (or sometimes [AnyDesk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AnyDesk), but it doesn't matter)... being connected to their PC, I ask em to show me their problems and issues...We then continue chatting through Visual Studio (the user's Visual Studio as I am connected through TeamViewer) by comments in the code editor...

Like, in Visual Basic, we chat like:

```
 code here
'''What is your issue?
''My issue Is...
 code here
```

If C#,

```
 code here
///What is your issue?
///My issue Is...
 Code here
```

I write code for them. It generally takes me 20-30 minutes at maximum to fix their entire issue...

Each line of code I write, I explain using comments...

When I am done fixing their issue, they thank for another 2 minutes... Then they say:

```
'''People on SO downvoted me... :(

or sometimes

'''feel sad that my question was closed
```

I reply:

```
''Listen, if you think I helped you than know this. I learnt almost everything myself... And the one who helped me more than I can explain is Stack&nbsp;Overflow...

 The OP:

 '''Then why didn't they answer my question?

 Me:

 '''Your question is off-topic, duplicate, or not standard... Such questions were answered previously, but now as SO's T&C and policy changed, such questions won’t be answered any more...That's why I invited you on Skype, so that you don't feel left put and quit just because you got some
downvotes... And from next time on, try to add *what you tried* in your post... You see, not everybody would waste their
 valuable 30 minutes to solve your issues...Byee

 '''Thanks again
```

This is exactly how each and every chat ends...If you don't believe me, why don't you ask the users who went to the chats if I scammed them or not...

If only one person says that *the guy who invited me in Skype cheated/scammed/took money from me/had evil intentions*, I swear I’d give up programming...

I am still a learner with very less experience of work, but a huge experience of not getting a good teaching (you guys said a lot of things without even knowing my situation... :(  )

Comment: Thanks again for 1. coming forward and 2. for explaining why/how you go about trying to help others. As stated in my post and some comments, I appreciate all the contributions that you add to SO and the individuals that you go out of your way to help. As a user, I think you are great and look forward to seeing many of your posts in the future. The only issue I found was *how* you went about helping others (specifically taking the help off site). I think you have good intentions and I'm willing to bet there are many grateful users whom you have helped directly...

Comment: ...The post was not aimed at you but at the actions of guiding users off site for help. I hope you will continue to contribute to SO and not be discouraged by this post but use it as a possibly learning opportunity for the future. Thanks again

Comment: i helped more than 10 users till today(since the last few weeks) .. if any user comes forward saying i did one wrong thing , i will leave programming forever

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to believe you're anything but a good person with good intentions. People here are mostly not concerned with the idea that you are a scammer or otherwise dishonest; it's just that this kind of help doesn't really fit how the site works. (Plus, while that's your business and yours alone, I predict it'll burn you out very quickly....)

Comment: @Pekka웃 , i respect ur words....I will try not to do this again :( .... And didn't quiet understand the last thing u said(`while that's your business and yours alone, I predict it'll burn you out very quickly`) ??

Comment: To elaborate on "how the site works", Stack Overflow is meant to be a library of great programming answers for *future readers* to enjoy, not just the person we're helping out at the moment. By taking the interaction away from the site, nothing is left for those future readers, you know?

Comment: What I meant by "burning out": my experience is offering custom unpaid programming support is often not very rewarding and one can lose the motivation to help altogether if done too much. There's an endless sea of people with programming problems and we can't fix them all; and sometimes people just need to learn how to fix them themselves. I'm finding the Stack Overflow model (where you write something knowing that ideally it'll be read by many many people in the future) is potentially much more rewarding.

Comment: Don't mind me asking but posting on SO is rewarding ?? How ?? some upvotes u mean ?? And i don't really do it for rewards... :( .. Just love it

Comment: I mean rewarding psychologically. Upvotes are a part of it (although the thrill doesn't last), but mostly in the sense that you are contributing in a small way to a library of knowledge that helps others. Not in a material sense. In a material sense there's almost always much more profitable things one could (and sometimes, but not always, should) be doing. :)

Comment: As a student , what more can i do ?? I am working on a personal project myself which blew away(sorry for bragging) devs i met online but nobody really agrees to help with my proj .. had been working alone on it for the last 1 year.. :( So , i don't want to see anybody like me who doesn't get help :( .. That's why i help..Hope other's understand ... If no,they can ban me :(

Comment: That's fine - and there is no hard rule on Stack Overflow banning what you are doing. We don't encourage offering off-site help, we don't think it's a great idea, and if you offer help *very* often it may cause suspicion (because it *could* be a scam! We here have no way to know.) But there is no rule against putting your E-Mail or skype contact info in your user profile and offering your help there, and from time to time telling a user in need of a helping hand that they can contact you offsite.

Comment: wait...i can add skype profile link in my SO profile ??? I thought only Twitter and own website is allowed to add ? And even if i add my skype link , if i ask em to contact me , then in future , someone will again post something like this regarding me and my behaviour ;( .. what to do ? i guess nothing

Comment: You can add any text you like, including links and an offer to help, in the main profile text. I'm not a moderator, but I can't imagine you getting shut down if you limit *actively* offering help to reasonable quantities and ideally don't post Skype links.

Comment: so u suggest that i add skype links in my profile and comment(if the OP is a beginner and didn't get answered) to find my skype link from my profile ?

Comment: I can't speak for moderators - I'm just a user - but I don't think anyone can seriously object to a Skype link in your profile text.

Comment: I'll turn these comments into an answer of its own.

Comment: I want to call attention to this statement you made:  "I cannot risk answering off-topic qs on this site..So i ask the OPs to join on SKYPE".  **You shouldn't be answering off-topic questions.  Period.**  You should be flagging them.  I believe you had good intentions when you set out to do this, and I hope I didn't suggest anything otherwise in my earlier answer.  But you should *really* be shutting down off-topic questions instead of letting the survive somehow.

Comment: @Makoto,  can i, add my skyoe id in my profile on SO,and if a qs is not amswered/closed,ask them to see my profile to find me??  or should i stop doing it at all??

Comment: I'd say stop doing it tbh - it defeats the point of the site in many ways to have answers squirreled away in chats we'll never be able to search on.  It also reduces the burden on you; you're a beginner in programming (your words), and given that people who would be asking are likely beginners, it's best to not have "the blind lead the blind".  Lastly, it also protects you from some horrible behavior from people online.  These sites are thoroughly moderated.  Nothing's stopping some jerk from posting offensive material in your Skype chat.

Comment: understood,  thanks man...will keep thia mind :)