# Etiquette: contact user on another network

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Is it considered a bad practice to contact a user on another network?
Send a LinkedIn invite for example?

Comment: Why do you want to contact them to begin with?   Are you discussing a potential job offer for them?

Comment: Just have some expert into your contacts.

Comment: I'll wait, perhaps some one flags it a s duplicate to corroborate it's not unfriendly.

Comment: @Makoto Does it matter why someone wants to contact someone else?  SO is neither of the person's Mom or protector.

Comment: How are downvotes unfriendly? People either disagree that it's something you should do, or know of a dupe and think you could have searched this more. How is any of this unfriendly? People have to stop seeing downvotes as anything but what they are....

Comment: Just discourages me from getting involved. Feels this site has a different approach than SO itself.

Comment: Sure, it's a different model than the main site a bit... still I can't see how any of what happened can be qualified as 'unfriendly'....

Comment: Thanks @Patrice for taking the time to comment.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't let a couple downvotes on meta discourage you :). Since meta downvotes don't impact rep, they do tend to flow more freely than on the main site. Most people who ask on meta have a couple of downvoted posts. That doesn't mean you can't learn from your posts or that they are valueless :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My philosophy is that it's fair game to contact anyone who leaves contact info in their profile (and this has been done with [mixed success](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261178/1079354)), but it's fair game for them to *ignore* any unsolicited communications.

Full disclosure:  I ignore about 100% of LinkedIn requests I get unless I know you in person, and even *then* it's a toss-up.  This goes for recruiters too.