# Harassing email from user

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

Closed a question from a new user as a duplicate and a few hours later got an email with the following (censoring mine):

> "duplicated? f**k you f**k you f**k you....
>
> I want to disable save dialog box. But its not work d******d. is this
>   question is duplicated? f**k you f**k you f**k you....
>
> I want to disable save dialog box. But its not work d******d. I hear
>   you from whorehouse"

Not looking to publicly shame this person who seems to have an apparent temper issue, but is there something that should be done about them? A time out perhaps? I've flagged the question for mod attention with a similar comment.

Kinda, sorta seems to fly in the face of this whole new be nice policy.

Comment: Flagging is pretty much your best option here. Maybe the "contact us" form? Something should be done. Not by us, but someone (mods) should have a talk with the offender here

Comment: If you haven't flagged them by now, flag them.  ***Now***.  Send a moderator this information.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261178/1079354

Comment: *"seems to fly in the face of this whole new be nice policy"* I don't think there was ever a version of the be nice policy where this was acceptable.

Comment: The OP has probably already abandoned that account/email and moved to one from its backup pool:(   Nothing effective can be done to sanction new users - they can say anything they wish, and their targets just have to put up with it.

Comment: @MartinJames Well this particular account has been around for over four years and only has a handful of rep.

Comment: <sigh> A week later and my flag is still pending and the user's account is still active.

Comment: @j08691 - Sorry this is taking so long to process. It's hard for us to associate what goes on outside the site with activity on it, in order to prevent innocent users from being framed by others (which has been attempted in the past). Could you forward this email on to SE employees and reference the post you'd flagged? There should be identifying information in the email that they should be able to use to tie that to the main user, and SE employees are usually the ones who act on offsite threats and harassment. Again, sorry for the delay, we wanted to be sure about this.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks Brad. What email address should I forward it to?

Comment: @j08691 - I think team@stackoverflow.com should get through to the right people. That's where I send the *impolite* emails I occasionally get.

Comment: @BradLarson Thank you